# mongodb push element into array of objects

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection with a following schema:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("4ee3ddc346b3b8880a000000"),
  ...
  "msgs" : [{
      "mid" : ObjectId("4ee3ddc346b3b8880a000000"),
      "deleted" : []
    },
    {
      "mid" : ObjectId("4ee3ddc346b3b8880a000100"),
      "deleted" : []
    }]
}
```

I want to do this query:
for the specific _id insert into each "deleted" array an element

so after doing this query I will receive something like this:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("4ee3ddc346b3b8880a000000"),
  ...
  "msgs" : [{
      "mid" : ObjectId("4ee3ddc346b3b8880a000000"),
      "deleted" : [2]
    },
    {
      "mid" : ObjectId("4ee3ddc346b3b8880a000100"),
      "deleted" : [2]
    }]
}
```

What I tried to do:

```
db.dialogs.update(
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4ee3ddc346b3b8880a000000")},
{$addToSet : {'msgs.$.deleted' : 2}}
)
```

the problem is that it only updating the first element element in the array, instead of all the elements

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669178/how-to-update-multiple-array-elements-in-mongodb

Answer (score 1):

Specify the multiple update option:

```
db.dialogs.update(
  { "_id" : ObjectId("4ee3ddc346b3b8880a000000")},
  {$addToSet : {'msgs.$.deleted' : 2}},
  false,
  true
)
```

The last parameter `true` tells mongodb to update all matching documents. (the third parameter tells mongodb not to do upset).

PS: the above assumes your original query and $ operation is correct, I didn't confirm that in MongoDB.

Comment: incorrect. What he wants here is to update several elements of a single document. Not all matching documents.