# MongoDB: Doing $inc on multiple keys

Tags: mongodb, php-mongodb

I need help incrementing value of all keys in *participants* without having to know name of the keys inside of it.

```
> db.conversations.findOne()

{
"_id" : ObjectId("4faf74b238ba278704000000"),
"participants" : {
    "4f81eab338ba27c011000001" : NumberLong(2),
    "4f78497938ba27bf11000002" : NumberLong(2)
}
}
```

I've tried with something like

```
$mongodb->conversations->update(array('_id' => new \MongoId($objectId)), array('$inc' => array('participants' => 1)));
```

to no avail...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to redesign your schema. It is never a good idea to have "random key names". Even though MongoDB is schemaless, it still means you need to have defined key names. You should change your schema to:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("4faf74b238ba278704000000"),
    "participants" : [
        { _id: "4f81eab338ba27c011000001", count: NumberLong(2) },
        { _id: "4f78497938ba27bf11000002", count: NumberLong(2) }
    ]
}
```

Sadly, even with that, you can't update all embedded counts in one command. There is currently an open feature request for that: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1243

In order to still update everything, you should:

- query the document
- update all the counts on the client side
- store the document again

In order to prevent race conditions with that, have a look at ["Compare and Swap"](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Atomic+Operations#AtomicOperations-%22UpdateifCurrent%22) and following paragraphs.

Comment: Ok, I've updated schema and all methods according to your example, however when doing a update by running your code above error message "can't append to array using string field name [count]" is displayed.

Comment: You're right. There is a Jira ticket for this: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1243 Please vote for it! I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to update all nested elements in one single move in current version of MongoDB. So I can advice to use "foreach {}".

Read realted topic: [How to Update Multiple Array Elements in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669178/how-to-update-multiple-array-elements-in-mongodb)

I hope this feature will be implemented in next version.