# Updating all instances of embedded documents in mongo, with one update operation

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

Within a mongodb collection, I have documents that contain lists of embedded documents that look like this (using `pymongo` with `col` being an instance of `pymongo.collection.Collection`):

```
In [1]: col.find_one({'reqid': 1})
Out[1]: 
{u'_id': ObjectId('4fa3446f1d41c81bba000000'),
 u'reports': [{u'comments': [u'A']},
              {u'comments': [u'B']},
              {u'comments': [u'A', u'B']},
              {u'comments': [u'C']},
              {u'comments': [u'A', u'B', u'C']}],
 ...} # Other fields
```

I now want with one `$set` update to reset all `comments` within a document to the empty list. I have tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
In [2]: col.update({'reqid': 1}, {'$set': {'reports.comments': []}})
In [3]: col.find_one({'reqid': 1}, {'reports.comments': 1})
Out[3]: 
{u'_id': ObjectId('4fa3446f1d41c81bba000000'),
 u'reports': [{u'comments': [u'A']},
              {u'comments': [u'B']},
              {u'comments': [u'A', u'B']},
              {u'comments': [u'C']},
              {u'comments': [u'A', u'B', u'C']}]}
```

I looked into the `$ positional operator` for a possible solution but still can't figure it out. Its pretty straight forward to write the logic in python to do this but would definitely appreciate the elegance of doing this purely with a single `pymongo.collection.Collection.update` call. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to preserve reports as an array with a bunch of identical entries of {u'comments':[]} members?  As many as there were before the update?

Comment: Yes. I have oversimplified the contents of report above. Each element of reports contains many more fields than just comments. I want to thus preserve all other fields and just set comments to [].

Comment: Again, this question has asked at least three times in the past week...

Comment: Wasn't aware that there was a JIRA issue opened for this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669178/how-to-update-multiple-array-elements-in-mongodb) as linked by a previous answer to a similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669178/how-to-update-multiple-array-elements-in-mongodb)