# MongoDB: Update property of subarray just updates the first element

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-update

The matching element looks like that:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "519ebd1cef1fce06f90e3157"
    },
    "from": "Tester2",
    "to": "Tester",
    "messages": [
        {
            "username": "Tester2",
            "message": "heeey",
            "read": false
        },
        {
            "username": "Tester",
            "message": "hi!",
            "read": false
        },
        {
            "username": "Tester2",
            "message": "test",
            "read": false
        }
    ],
}
```

Now I try to set the `read` property to the current date just of the subelements where the username is not equal to `Tester`:

```
var messages = db.collection('messages');
messages.update(
{
    _id: new BSON.ObjectID("519ebd1cef1fce06f90e3157"),
    messages: {
        $elemMatch: { username: { $ne: "Tester" } }
    }
},
{ $set: { 'messages.$.read': new Date() } },
{ multi: true }, function(error, result) {
    console.log(error);
    console.log(result);
});
```

But just the first messages subelement `read` property updates:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "519ebd1cef1fce06f90e3157"
    },
    "from": "Tester2",
    "to": "Tester",
    "messages": [
        {
            "username": "Tester2",
            "message": "heeey",
            "read":  {
                "$date": "2013-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
            }
        },
        {
            "username": "Tester",
            "message": "hi!",
            "read": false
        },
        {
            "username": "Tester2",
            "message": "test",
            "read": false
        }
    ],
}
```

What's wrong with the code?
I'm using node.js v0.10.8 and MongoDB v2.4.3 together with [node-mongodb-native](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your code; the [`$` operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/positional/#op._S_) contains the index of the *first* matching array element.  The `{multi: true}` option only makes the `update` apply to multiple documents, not array elements.  To update multiple array elements in a single `update` you must specify them by numeric index.

So you'd have to do something like this:

```
messages.update(    
    {
        _id: new BSON.ObjectID("519ebd1cef1fce06f90e3157")
    },
    { $set: { 
        'messages.0.read': new Date(),
        'messages.2.read': new Date()
    } },
    function (err, result) { ... }
);
```

Comment: Okay and if I don't know the index before? Couldn't I not simply use `messages.$.read`?

Comment: You'd need to do a separate query to get all the messages so you could determine the indexes (obviously a total pain).  `$` will be 0 (the index of the first matched element), so it will only reference the first element.  In short, MongoDB doesn't really support what you're trying to do.

Comment: sounds like your schema is not a good choice for your use case then.

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to question: [How to Update Multiple Array Elements in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669178/how-to-update-multiple-array-elements-in-mongodb)

```
var set = {}, i, l;
for(i=0,l=messages.length;i<l;i++) {
  if(messages[i].username != 'tester') {
    set['messages.' + i + '.read'] = new Date();
  }
}

.update(objId, {$set:set});
```

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a little bit late to answer this question but if you use the $[] operator, it will do the trick.

- more details here
  https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/
- I was able to use it inside an updateMany operation, but it should work also for update

```
var messages = db.collection('messages');
messages.update(
{
    _id: new BSON.ObjectID("519ebd1cef1fce06f90e3157"),
    messages: {
        $elemMatch: { username: { $ne: "Tester" } }
    }
},
{ $set: { 'messages.$[].read': new Date() } },
{ multi: true }, function(error, result) {
    console.log(error);
    console.log(result);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think ArrayFilters can be used in this case