# MongoDB multiple array element update

Tags: mongodb

Is there any way to update multiple elements of an array embedded in one field of a mongo document?

ex:

```
db.exampleCollection.update({
    "_id" : "00000002522dde26c6d65aed",
    "array.priority" : {$gt : 4}
}, {$inc : {"array.$.priority" : 10} }, false, true);
```

This doesn't update multiple elements, only updates one element

Comment: can you please share the document structure you have and the document structure you want to achieve to add more clarity to your question.

Comment: you are only posting the query. Can you also post a sample document you have and sample output you are trying to achieve

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to update multiple array elements in mongodb](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669178/how-to-update-multiple-array-elements-in-mongodb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to affect multiple array elements per-doc in an `update` is to use numeric indexes in your keys to specifically identity the elements to update by their array position:

```js
db.exampleCollection.update({
    "_id" : "00000002522dde26c6d65aed"
}, {
    $inc: {
        "array.0.priority": 10, 
        "array.1.priority": 10
    } 
}, false, true);
```

I know you are trying to target elements where `priority > 4` rather than by index, but that's the harsh reality.

Comment: Does anyone know if there any way to do this more succinctly if updating several adjacent fields? Slice-style notation would be nice - ie. $inc : { "array.0:10.priority":10} to increment all values in positions 0 to 10