# How to find a document and update its list in mongoDB with java drivers?

Tags: java, mongodb

I want to find a document by some values in objects from one list and update that list object values.
While it finds the document by the list values and subtracts the value of topups.total.cnt and topups.total.revenue (if it didn't then they would be 3 and 36000000), it doesn't change the false to true except for the first object
in the list.
I think this line

```
"updateObj.append("$set", new BasicDBObject("topups.data.$.isRb", true))"
```

is the problem. It doesn't update the the object that the myQuery defines. 
The below false should all be true after running the code three times.

```
"topups" : {
            "data" : [
                {
                        "val" : 12000000,
                        "chId" : 2,
                        "reqSys" : "222220002899",
                        "old" : NumberLong(189398),
                        "isRb" : true
                },
                {
                        "val" : 12000000,
                        "chId" : 2,
                        "reqSys" : "222220002899",
                        "old" : NumberLong(189398),
                        "isRb" : false
                },
                {
                        "val" : 12000000,
                        "chId" : 2,
                        "reqSys" : "222220002899",
                        "old" : NumberLong(189398),
                        "isRb" : false
                }
            ],
        "total" : {
                "cnt" : 0,
                "revenue" : 0
        }
},
```

This is the code..

```
BasicDBObject myQuery = new BasicDBObject();
myQuery.append("d", new BasicDBObject("$gte", dayOfYear - 2).append("$lte", dayOfYear))
.append("m", msisdn)
.append("topups.data.reqSys", reqSystem)
.append("topups.data.isRb", false)
.append("topups.data.chId", 2)
.append("topups.data.old", preEventBalance)
.append("topups.data.val", callCost);

BasicDBObject updateObj = new BasicDBObject();
updateObj.append("$set", new BasicDBObject("topups.data.$.isRb", true))
.append("$inc", new BasicDBObject("topups.total.revenue", -callCost)
.append("topups.total.cnt", -1));

mongoDBcollection.update(myQuery, updateObj);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like the same question as this: [How to Update Multiple Array Elements in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4669178/653519)

The answer, sadly, being that you cannot, in a single operation, update all documents in an array.

Comment: Eventually I made a query and a document $pull and then a same document $push with the isRb set to true.
That is two operations.

Comment: If you can answer your own question with complete code with `$pull` and `$push` it would be nice. Contribute and share your knowledge is always good

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this,

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#update-a-document-element

The document (for 2.4 ) says that it will only update the first element of an array. So I guess can't be done using the $ operator.

You can try and do it either by updating individual element, like "topups.data.1.isRb" : true or Create an array outside with updated values and replace the entire array.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to update all the records at once (as the above ticket from dex mentions or the link for the question Trisha mentions). I want to update one at a time.

So, if the code above runs one time (and all "isRb" is false), all three list members match "myQuery" so I want one of three to be changed to "true" (not all three).

Second time the code runs, two list members match "myQuery" so I want one of two to be changed to "true" (not all two).

Third time the code runs, only one list member matches "myQuery" so I want that one to be changed to "true" (after all it is the only one left "false" after two runs).