# How to update objects in array in Mongo

Tags: mongodb, updates

I'm quite good at SQL, but I'm struggling with even the simplest Mongo queries.

My documents in the `post` collection looks like this (simplified)

```
{
     '_id': 5
     'body': 'Correct horse battery staple',
     'comments': 
     [{
          user_id: '123'
      }, 
      {
          user_id: '456'
      }, 
      {
          user_id: '123'
      }]
}
```

I need to update the `user_id's` that are `'123'` to `'abc'` for all posts.

In a SQL database, I would have a `post` table and a `comment` table and do this:

```
UPDATE comment SET user_id = 'abc' WHERE user_id = '123'
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to update multiple array elements in mongodb](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669178/how-to-update-multiple-array-elements-in-mongodb)

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for [FindAndModify](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/findAndModify/):

```
db.runCommand({
  findAndModify: "post",
  query: { user_id: 123 },
  update: { $set: { user_id: 'abc' } }
})
```

**Edit**

I believe you can do a similar thing on a collection with [update](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#db.collection.update) if `multi` is set to `true`:

```
db.post.update(
  { user_id: 123 },
  { $set: { user_id: 'abc' } },
  { multi: true }
)
```

Comment: I need to modify *all* documents, not just one. I updated my question to be more explicit.

Answer (score 1):

By default, mongodb update command will update only one document.

```
db.collection.update({document to be found},{changes to be done})
```

To update multiple document, you should include **multi** keyword.

```
db.collection.update({document to be found},{changes to be done},{multi:true})
```

Assuming your document structure as below:

```
{
    "_id": 5,
    "body": "Correct horse battery staple",
    "comments": [{"user_id": "123"},{"user_id": "456"},{"user_id": "123"}]
}
{
    "_id": 6,
    "body": "Correct horse battery staple",
    "comments": [{"user_id': "23"},{"user_id": "123"},{"user_id": "13"}]
}
```

In this case, i may need to update multiple elements inside an array as well as multiple documents. There is no default mongodb query to do it. 
Instead i will loop through documents and do it as follows.

```
// loop until all documents has been updated
while(db.post.find({'comments.user_id':'123'}).count()!=0) 
{
    db.post.update(
                     { 'comments.user_id':'123' },
                     { $set:{'comments.$.user_id':'abc'} },
                     { multi:true }
                   )
}
```

After the 1st loop run, **post collection** will look like:

```
{
    "_id": 5,
    "body": "Correct horse battery staple",
    "comments": [{"user_id": "abc"},{"user_id": "456"},{"user_id": "123"}]
}
{
    "_id": 6,
    "body": "Correct horse battery staple",
    "comments": [{"user_id": "23"},{"user_id": "abc"},{"user_id": "13"}]
}
```

After the 2nd loop run, **post collection** will look like:

```
{
    "_id": 5,
    "body": "Correct horse battery staple",
    "comments": [{"user_id": "abc"},{"user_id": "456"},{"user_id": "abc"}]
}
{
    "_id": 6,
    "body": "Correct horse battery staple",
    "comments": [{"user_id": "23"},{"user_id": "abc"},{"user_id": "13"}]
}
```

**In the third loop run, the loop gets terminated.**

Answer (score 0):

You can use [arrayFilters](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/) from v3.6,

```
db.post.updateMany(
  { 'comments.user_id': '123' },
  { 
    $set: {
      'comments.$[elem].user_id': 'abc' 
    }
  },
  { 
    arrayFilters: [
      { 'elem.user_id': '123' }
    ]
  }
);
```