# How to update a String with an Array in a document within Robo3T?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, robo3t

I am trying to change an element object that is within an array in a document on Robo3T.

The structure looks like this:

```
  {
    "_id" : ObjectId("1234"),
    "source" : "BW",
    "sourceTableName" : "lwtrmls",
    "tableName" : "tier",
    "type" : "main",
    "primaryKeys" : [ 
        {
            "sourceField" : "tier_id", // <~~~~ This is what I am trying to update!
            "reportingField" : "bw_id",
            "type" : "integer"
        }
    ]
}
```

Basically trying to change `tier_id` under `primaryKeys` and `sourceField` to `trmls_id`.

I have tried something like `db.my_collection.update( {_id : "1234"}, {$set : {"primaryKeys.0.tier_id" : "trmls_id"}} )` and that does not seem to be working. Is there a clean way to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to update objects in array in Mongo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20668875/how-to-update-objects-in-array-in-mongo)

Comment: If primary keys contains more than one object? What should be the condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you need to use [$(update)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/)

In you case you need to execute current query:

```
db.my_collection.update( {_id : "1234", "primaryKeys.sourceField":"tier_id"}, {$set : {"primaryKeys.$.sourceField" : "trmls_id"}} )
```

Updated:

If you want to update not only first element in array for current filters, but all, you could use [$[]](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/)

```
db.my_collection.update( {_id : "1234", "primaryKeys.sourceField":"tier_id"}, {$set : {"primaryKeys.$[].sourceField" : "trmls_id"}, { multi: true }} )
```

Comment: updates all not matching fields also, This is not the way to update, it requires arrayFilters and this is duplicate question. answers are already in above comment link.