# How to add an extra field in a sub document in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

I've just started working with MongoDB. And I have a document like this:

```js
   {

     "_id": "12345" 
     "body": "Here is the body" 
     "comments":[
                {
                  "name": "Person 1"
                  "comm": "My comment"},
                {
                  "name": "Person 2"
                  "comm": "Comment 2"}
             ] 
    "author":"Author 1" 
}
```

And I want to change this document to :

```js
   {

    "_id": "12345" 
     "body": "Here is the body" 
     "comments":[
                {
                  "name": "Person 1"
                  "comm": "My comment"
                  "checks_": 1
                 },
                {
                  "name": "Person 2"
                  "comm": "Comment 2"
                  "checks_": 4
                }
             ] 
    "author": "Author 1" 
}
```

I've tried:

```js
db.coll.update({ "_id":12345},{ "$set":{ "comments" :{ "checks_": 1}}})
```

And this removed all sub documents within comments and added `{checks_:1}` to it.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to update multiple array elements in mongodb](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669178/how-to-update-multiple-array-elements-in-mongodb)

Comment: Couldn't find the solution that'd help me..

Comment: If you want to update a single array subdocument you can do db.coll.update({_id:12345},{$set:{"comments.0.checks_":1}}). This will update the document at array index 0.

Comment: What if i need to do in all sub array in one go?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So what you are doing wrong is that the [`$set`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) operator is doing exactly what it should, and it is **replacing** *only* the `comments` field with the value you have specified. This is not adding an additional document to the array.

You need to be **specific** and use "dot notation" to *"indentify"* which array element you are replacing. So to get to your result, you need **two** updates:

```
db.coll.update({ "_id":12345},{ "$set":{ "comments.0.checks_" : 1 }})
db.coll.update({ "_id":12345},{ "$set":{ "comments.1.checks_" : 4 }})
```

That is at least until the next version (as of writing) of MongoDB is released, where you can do [bulk updates](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/command/update/#bulk-update). And that will not be long now.

Answer (score 1):

A little more geneirc solution (for MongoDb 3.6+):

```
db.coll.update(
{},
{$set: {"comments.$[element].checks_": 1}},
{multi: false, arrayFilters: [{"element.name": {$eq: "Person 1"}}]}
)
```

This will add field into specific sub document from the list, matching criteria (name = 'Person 1').

Answer (score 0):

Adding my two cents here.
If you want to add a field to the all the cells, with the same value (in this example: 1 will be added to all of them). You can use the following command:

```
db.coll.updateMany( {"_id": 12345}, {"$set": {"comments.$[].checks_": 1} }});
```

And you will get

```
{

    "_id": "12345" 
     "body": "Here is the body" 
     "comments":[
                {
                  "name": "Person 1"
                  "comm": "My comment"
                  "checks_": 1
                 },
                {
                  "name": "Person 2"
                  "comm": "Comment 2"
                  "checks_": 1
                },
                ...
                {
                  "name": "Person 300"
                  "comm": "Comment 300"
                  "checks_": 1
                }
             ] 
    "author": "Author 1" 
}
```