# How to update an array of multiple elements in mongodb..?

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I have a requirement to update an array of multiple elements.My collections is  in the following way

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("53e87e239ae974e6a0a81004"),
"name" : "mulagala",
"notifications" : [
    {
        "name" : "apple",
        "status" : 0
    },
    {
        "name" : "microsoft",
        "status" : 0
    },
    {
        "name" : "android",
        "status" : 0
    }
]
}
```

now  i want to change the every status element of the array should be changed to 1, ie.`status:1` with a single query.

I tried in the following way

```
db.mystatus.update({'notifications.status':0},{$set:{'notifications.$.status':1}},false,true)
```

But the first record only updating, what to do.Any help would be appriciated!

Comment: This is a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669178/how-to-update-multiple-array-elements-in-mongodb). Short answer is that this cannot be done using the positional operator `$`. There's [this issue](http://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1243) in JIRA you should vote for if you want this implemented. Answer in other question gives you an idea of how to go around this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried updating the elements of the array using the [$ operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#update-an-element-if-position-is-unknown) for arrays? Currently it updates only one element as the index is coded to 0.

Comment: @Seket, Tried that one also, but like you said only one element is updating, i need to update all the elements in the list

Comment: @Seket, this won't work because the positional `$` operator only matches the **first element** that matches the query document. For more info, see [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#up._S_).