# Updating all elements in array

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Hey I'm trying to update all subdocuments contained within an array using the following code

```
  setDuelToInactive: (duel) ->
    Duels.update({_id: duel._id}, $set: {active: false})
    userOneId = duel.userOneId
    userTwoId = duel.userTwoId

    Users.update({_id: userOneId}, { $set: { 'profile.character.souls.$.active': false} })
    Users.update({_id: userTwoId}, { $set: { 'profile.character.souls.$.active': false} })


    return
```

where the souls field in the Users collection is the array. I receive the following error message

```
MongoError: Cannot apply the positional operator without a corresponding query field containing an array.
```

Comment: The MongoDB server (as at 2.6) does not support updating all subdocuments in an array using the positional operator ($). The positional operator only applies to the first matching element. There is a feature request you can watch/upvote in the MongoDB issue tracker: [SERVER-1243: Use positional operator to update all items in an array](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1243). The fastest interim workaround would probably be to retrieve the document with the full array and do the required manipulation in your application code before saving.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the positional operator `$` to update al subdocuments inside an array. See [the documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/): the operator matches the **first** element of the array that matches the query.

This also means that your query should use the array field (`profile.character.souls`) somehow. Yours do not, hence the error.

At this moment there is no shortcut for what you intend to do, you need to list all indexes manually. See this question: [How to Update Multiple Array Elements in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669178/how-to-update-multiple-array-elements-in-mongodb)