# How to update a field in an array's subdocument contained in an array's subdocument in MongoDB using C# driver?

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a collection of documents in MongoDB with a structure like this (there are multiple container documents, each containing `Sessions`, each session contains 1 Order, each Order contains multiple Items):

```
{
  "Sessions" : [{
      "ID" : "1882a092-d395-45d1-b36b-e2fa3df81b95",
      "Order" : {
        "Items" : [{
            "_id" : "a9c94a5e-10ef-433d-9c63-f4555eb7c2a7",
            "Title" : "UPDATE THIS",
          }]
      }
    }],
  "_id" : "1b640bc4-fdb4-49b1-9c60-e4c6f1bd0405"
}
```

I would like to update `Title` of a given `Item` within an Order in a Session while knowing the `_id` of the Item (I also know ID of the Session if that helps):

I have tried the following:

```
col.Update(Query.EQ("Sessions.ID", sessionID),
                Update.Set("Sessions.$.Order.Items.Title", newTitle));

col.Update(Query.EQ("Sessions.Order.Items._id", id),
                Update.Set("Sessions.Order.Items.$.Title", newTitle));
```

Both throw an exception `WriteConcern detected an error 'cannot use the part (Sessions of Sessions.Order.Items.0.Status) to traverse the element ...`. I also tried different combinations of combined queries using `Query.And` which probably make so little sense that they are not worth posting here.

**How to update field in a subdocument contained in an array of documents using the C# driver?**

I realize this cannot be done with the positional operator alone (and the positional operator will not magically match inner array).

I am looking for out of the box solutions how to accomplish this kind of update without changing the schema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer from @Disposer helped me find a solution for this. It spreads multiple areas in my codebase but I would like to share the basic gist with others who may have a similar problem.

These are the steps:

- Lock the given Order and do not allow items to be added into it (on application level).
- Alternatively, use a combination of an additional `WriteCount` field and by using `findAndModify` to atomically update the document only if it has not been updated in the meantime ("update if current").

Then, when updating `Title` for a given item:

- use stored `WriteCount`
- determine item index
- use the item index in combination with the positional operator: `$` to identify the session, an integer `index` to target the item, while employing "update if current" strategy using the `WriteCount` field.

The update part then becomes:

```
"Sessions.$.Order.Items." + index + ".Title"
```

Comment: Better answer can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31804925/update-field-in-array-mongodb-c-sharp-driver

Answer (score 5):

Your are not updating sub-document of a sub-document.
Your are updating one field of an array's sub-document that is inside the parent array's sub-document.

You can update the **first** element by the code blow

```
col.Update(Query.EQ("Sessions.ID", sessionID),
                Update.Set("Sessions.$.Order.Items.0.Title", newTitle));
```

with a simple update query you cant update **all** elements' Title.
This link might help you (with custom JavaScript update query)

[How to multi update of a nested array in MondoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26438864/how-to-multi-update-of-a-nested-array-in-mondodb/26439401#26439401)