# Update field in array mongodb c# driver

Tags: c#, arrays, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, mongodb-csharp-2.0

I try to update `status` field for object from `p2l` array

```
var update = Builders<BsonDocument>.Update.Set("p2l.$.status",BsonValue.Create(status))
```

It seems that code will work fine, but how to implement it with typed builder and set all fields with lambda ?
I found a solution by the following link 
[How to update a field in an array's subdocument contained in an array's subdocument in MongoDB using C# driver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26783794/how-to-update-a-field-in-an-arrays-subdocument-contained-in-an-arrays-subdocum)

But it  suitable only for old version of driver.

Comment: You do realize "why" this is notated in this way and therefore not a function applied to array members as with a lambda don't you? Two different things. The purpose here is to "match" the array element in the "query" expression of the update. Then the "matched index" is notated in this way so the correct element is updated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
Builders<Person>.Update.Set(x => x.Pets[-1].Name, "Fluffencutters")
```

Note *-1* index on Pets collection, that means to apply set for all elements.
I found this solution by exploring [UpdateDefinitionBuilderTests](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/master/src/MongoDB.Driver.Tests/UpdateDefinitionBuilderTests.cs).