# mongoengine bulk update fields with JSON

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, mongoengine

I am new to Mongodb and Mongoengine. And I am wondering if there is a way to bulk update MongoDB fields with a json script, for instance:

```
jsonData = {'name': 'Stak', 'password':'oVeRfLoW'}
User.objects.get(username='u_name').update(jsonData)
```

Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mongodb's built-in update function, [db.collection.update()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/) is very customizable, has options for updating multiple documents at once and doesn't require getting anything beforehand.

You can use it like so:

```
db.collection.update(
   <query>,
   <update>,
   {
     upsert: <boolean>,
     multi: <boolean>,
     writeConcern: <document>
   }
)
```

So in this case:

```
db.collection.update(
   {username:'u_name'}, //1
   {$set:jsonData}, // 2
   {
     multi: true, // 3
   }
)
```

(

1. the query searches for documents that have
2. $set is IMPORTANT! If you do not use $set, your entire document will be erased and updated to a document containing only your new values. (it will delete all the other fields)
3. Update multiple documents at once.

Keep in mind this is a guideline and you'll have to modify the above code a bit.

Comment: Thank you! A follow up question: suppose I use the code you provided above, and I want to update a ListField like so: 'credentials': [ {'cid': 001, 'alias': 'blah'}, {'cid': 001, 'alias': 'blah'}]. And I want to update each 'alias' of these credentials to 'bah'. What should the query be? I tried using the {$set: {credentials: {$each: {'alias': 'bah'} } } } but it throws errors;

Comment: Not sure, that's a tough one. I'd look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669178/how-to-update-multiple-array-elements-in-mongodb seems to have an answer that may work. The latest answer (march 1) is likely good.