# Is there a way to add a new field to a collection dynamically in meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Suppose you have a collection called `bar` in a MongoDB, which has the following items :

```
"items" : [
    {
        "item_name" : "my_item_one",
        "price" : 20
    },
    {
        "item_name" : "my_item_two",
        "price" : 50
    },
    {
        "item_name" : "my_item_three",
        "price" : 30
    }
]
```

How can i add a new field called `discount` to each entry in the `items` array? I tried this without luck :

```
var dynamicItem = "items.$.discount"
    Bar.update( {user_id : 123456} , {$set : {dynamicItem : 5} })
```

Comment: @mixel. thanks for editing my question If there is anyone out there with insights on how to achieve the above your help will be appreciated. Note that the part that is answered has been deleted and only the part without an answer is left.

Comment: do not delete the answered part. Some people might be looking out for an answer to same question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the first one is not possible at the moment, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669178/how-to-update-multiple-array-elements-in-mongodb) answer.

for the second one, try this:

```js
var dynamicItem = {};
dynamicItem["itemsCollectionName"] = "Beer pack";

Bar.update( {user_id : 123456} , {$set : dynamicItem })
```

Comment: Sweet, thanks. I've tried your code and it works. For the first one I'll try the work around they mentioned in the thread you referred me to. It kind of sucks that meteor does not currently have a way to support the first one

Comment: The work around in the thread is  not dynamic at all. Also the way they plan to utilize the positional operator in mongo will most probably not cater for dynamism - sad!

Comment: yeah, I know. glad I could help though.