# How to use C# Mongodb driver typed methods Update fields of array document elements

Tags: c#, arrays, mongodb, mongodb-csharp-2.0

Using the MongoDB C# Driver version 2.0.1 with Mongodb 3.0, is it possible to use typed methods to update an array field document element?

For example, I have the following document:

```
{
     Name:"Ken",
     ContactNo:[ { Number:"123", Type:"Mobile"},
                  { Number:"456", Type:"Office"},
                  { Number:"531", Type:"Fax"}
                ]
 }
```

How do I do the following operations using typed C# methods:

1) Update the `Type` field for all elements of the `ContactNo` array to be "`PABX`"

2) Update `ContactNo` array document element's `Type` field whose `Number` field equals "`123`"  to be "`Fiber`"

3) Update the first element of the `Contact` array and set its `Type` field to be "`Unknown`"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It's not currently possible to update all the items in an array using the positional operator. See [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669178) and [this MongoDB issue](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1243). However, if you know the number of elements in your array ahead of time (or can obtain it somehow), then this will work:

   ```
   var numberOfElementsInArray = 3;
   var filter = Builders<Contact>.Filter.Eq("Name", "Ken");
   var update = Builders<Contact>.Update.Combine(Enumerable.Range(0, numberOfElementsInArray)
           .Select(i => Builders<Contact>.Update.Set("ContactNo." + i + ".Type", "PABX")));
   collection.UpdateOneAsync(filter, update).Wait();
   ```
2. This code will set the `Type` property of the element in the `ContactNo` array with a `Number` of `123` to `Fiber`:

   ```
   var filter = Builders<Contact>.Filter.And(
           Builders<Contact>.Filter.Eq("Name", "Ken"),
           Builders<Contact>.Filter.Eq("ContactNo.Number", "123"));
   var update = Builders<Contact>.Update.Set("ContactNo.$.Type", "Fiber");
   collection.UpdateOneAsync(filter, update).Wait();
   ```
3. This code will set the `Type` property of the first element in the `ContactNo` array to `Unknown`:

   ```
   var filter = Builders<Contact>.Filter.Eq("Name", "Ken");
   var update = Builders<Contact>.Update.Set("ContactNo.0.Type", "Unknown");
   collection.UpdateOneAsync(filter, update).Wait();
   ```

Note that all of this code assumes that you have a class called `Contact` that corresponds to the data you specified in your question (your actual class might be called something else, I just called it `Contact` here), and that `collection` is an instance of `IMongoCollection<Contact>`.

For example:

```
var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");
var collection = client.GetDatabase("your database").GetCollection<Contact>("your collection name");
```