# Mongoose / MongoDB - How to push new array element onto correct parent array element

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

mongodb 3.0.7 
mongoose 4.1.12

I want to push new element :  "bbb"
onto groups array which lives inside outer orgs array ...

original mongo data from this :

```
{
    orgs: [
        {
            org: {
                _bsontype: "ObjectID",
                id: "123456789012"
            },
            groups: [
                "aaa"
            ]
        }
    ],
    _id: {
        _bsontype: "ObjectID",
        id: "888888888888"
    }
}
```

to this :

```
{
    orgs: [
        {
            org: {
                _bsontype: "ObjectID",
                id: "123456789012"
            },
            groups: [
                "aaa",
                "bbb"
            ]
        }
    ],
    _id: {
        _bsontype: "ObjectID",
        id: "888888888888"
    }
}
```

Here is a hardcoded solution yet I do not want 
to hardcode array index (see the 0 in : 'orgs.0.groups' )

```
dbModel.findByIdAndUpdate(

    { _id: ObjectId("888888888888".toHex()), 'orgs.org' : ObjectId("123456789012".toHex()) },
    {   $push : { 'orgs.0.groups' : 'bbb'  
                }
    },
    {   safe: true, 
        upsert: false, 
        new : true
    }
)
```

... I was hoping a simple 'orgs.$.groups' would work, but no.  Have also tried 'orgs.groups' , also no.
Do I really need to first retrieve the orgs array, identify the index
then perform some second operation to push onto proper orgs array element ?

PS - suggested duplicate answer does not address this question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update all elements in an array in mongodb](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33186596/update-all-elements-in-an-array-in-mongodb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found solution, had to use

```
dbModel.update
```

not

```
dbModel.findOneAndUpdate nor dbModel.findByIdAndUpdate
```

when using '$' to indicate matched array index in multi-level documents

```
'orgs.$.groups'
```

this code works :

```
dbModel.update(

    { _id: ObjectId("888888888888".toHex()), 'orgs.org' : ObjectId("123456789012".toHex()) },
    {   $push : { 'orgs.$.groups' : 'bbb'  
                }
    },
    {   safe: true, 
        upsert: false, 
        new : true
    }
)
```

I wonder if this is a bug in mongoose ?  Seems strange findOneAndUpdate fails to work.