# Mongodb error: The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query

Tags: arrays, mongodb, updates

I have a collection with objects like this

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5742be02289512cf98bf63e3"),
    "name" : "test1",
    "attributes" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "x",
            "color" : "0xd79c9c",
            "_id" : ObjectId("5742be02289512cf98bf63e8")
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "y",
            "color" : "0xd79c9c",
            "_id" : ObjectId("5742be02289512cf98bf63e7")
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "z",
            "color" : "0xd79c9c",
            "_id" : ObjectId("5742be02289512cf98bf63e6")
        }
    ],
    "__v" : 6
}
```

And I want to update all documents, and set for each attribute new field.
So I want to run a single query to update all documents at once. I think, this query will do

```js
db.spaces.update({}, { $set: { "attributes.0.weight": 2 } }, {multi: true})
```

But when I run this query, I get an error:

> "code" : 16837,
> "errmsg" : "The positional operator did not find the
> match needed from the query. Unexpanded update: attributes.$.weight"

I can't understand why.
Please help

Comment: You need to include the array field as part of the query document in order to use the positional operator.

Comment: @chridam, how I can do it ?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You need to include the array field as part of the query document in order to use the **[`positional operator`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/)**.

For example, if you want to update the first array element i.e. with `{ "attributes.name": "x" }` then you could follow the pattern:

```
db.spaces.update(
   { "attributes.name": "x" }, // <-- the array field must appear as part of the query document.
   { "$set": { "attributes.$.weight": 2 } },
   { "multi": true }
)
```

For the newer MongoDB versions `3.2.X`, you could use the **[`updateMany()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/)** method to update multiple documents within the collection based on the filter above.

Comment: db.spaces.update({"attributes.name": { $exists: true }}, { $set: {"attributes.$.weight": 3}}, {multi: true}) this query updates only first item in array

Comment: I need to update all elements in array for all documents

Comment: @Gor Oh I see, let me update the answer

Comment: @Gor Actually a duplicate exists which offers the solution

Comment: I cant understand, why { $exists: true} dont work? How I understand, it will match all elements in array

Comment: @Gor The reason why it won't work in this case is that  positional `$` operator acts as a placeholder for the **first** element that matches the query document, and not all the elements in the array. Consult the answers in the marked duplicate for a solution.

Comment: please give me link for duplicate, thank you

Comment: @Gor It's right there at the top of your question. In case you don't see it :) [**How to Update Multiple Array Elements in mongodb**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669178/how-to-update-multiple-array-elements-in-mongodb)

Answer (score 10):

The positional operator needs a match, from the match part of your update query.

for example:

```
db.spaces.update({ "attributes.name": "x" }, { $set: { "attributes.0.weight": 2 } }, {multi: true})
```

here the first parameter for update operation will match the array `attributes` where any element has a property `name=="x"`, for any element that matches the condition the position operator can be used to update it.

So, because `name='x'`, in this case the first matching element would be,

```
{
            "name" : "x",
            "color" : "0xd79c9c",
            "_id" : ObjectId("5742be02289512cf98bf63e8")
        },
```

and it will get updated.

Now from your question I understand you want to update the document in a way that in each document your first element, `attribute` gets a new value for `weight=2`.

you can do something like

```
db.spaces.update({ "attributes.name": { $regex: /^(?=[\S\s]{10,8000})[\S\s]*$/ } }, { $set: { "attributes.0.weight": 2 } }, {multi: true})
```

What we do here is match all element in array attribute. and we use the positional operator to update the first element of that array

Comment: this updates only first element in array

Comment: yes.. position operator `$` and `0` would only update the first element.

Comment: I will update my answer

Comment: Same question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33186596/update-all-elements-in-an-array-in-mongodb