# Monogo Mulit update for nested arrays

Tags: mongodb

So I'm trying to push an object into a nested array for all matching records.

here is the basic structure:

```
{
 client:'client_name',
 items:[
  {
    name:'item_one',
    status:'LIVE',
    period:[
     {
       name:'dec-15',
       owed: 20 
     }
    ]
  }
 ]
}
```

and what I'm trying to do is push an array into items.period for all live items.

here is the cli I used:

```
db.records.update({'items.status':'LIVE'},{$push:{'items.$.period':{name:'Aug-15',owed:20}}},{multi:true});
```

this works but only for the first record. I'm sure I'm screwing something up with the positional operator but I don't know what.

Comment: It only works for the first record contain `status:LIVE`?

Comment: Correct, Only works for the first nested item with the status:'LIVE'

Comment: Have you resolved this yet?

Comment: Nope Could really use some advice here. Its as if the update functions stop working after the first nest.

Comment: You won't be able to do it in one query, checkout the first to answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669178/how-to-update-multiple-array-elements-in-mongodb)