# MongoDB - Update an object in nested Array

Tags: mongodb, updates

```
{
  "_id": "xPBc4By8FemDwTPqH",
  "u": {
    "_id": "6PoZawHZcQz4Gwzcv",
    "username": "michael"
  },
  "friends": [
    {
      "u": {
        "_id": "eGqDjAjjtYADbuSnn",
        "username": "michael",
        "name": "michael"
      }
    },
    {
      "u": {
        "_id": "k4gKCGwYryXDMMHvs",
        "username": "joyce",
        "name": "joyce"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to update the name of "friends.u.username": "michael" 's name is "hello", how I need to do it.

Answer (score 109):

Apply the [`$set`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) operator together with the [**`$`** positional operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) in your update to change the `name` field.

The [**`$`** positional operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) will identify the correct element in the array to update without explicitly specifying the position of the element in the array, thus your final update statement should look like:

```
db.collection.update(
    { "friends.u.username": "michael" }, 
    { "$set": { "friends.$.u.name": "hello" } }
)
```

---

To update multiple elements in an array when more than one element matches the filter, you can use the [`$\[<identifier>\]`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/) syntax with the [`arrayFilters`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/release-notes/3.6/#std-label-3.6-arrayFilters) option. The following will update all matching elements in the "friends" array:

```
db.collection.update(
    { "friends.u.username": "michael" },
    { "$set": { "friends.$[elem].u.name": "hello" } },
    { 
      "arrayFilters": [{ "elem.u.username": "michael" }], 
      "multi": true 
    }
)
```

The `$[elem]` syntax identifies array elements that match the specified filter in the [`arrayFilters`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/release-notes/3.6/#std-label-3.6-arrayFilters) option. The `multi: true` option is added to update all matching documents instead of just the first one.

Comment: For some reason is not working for me... Nothing happen, but If I use `0` instead of `$`, the (wrong) element on array is changed

Comment: @Dherik Do you have a question already with the details for your problem? If not can you create one with a sample document and your desired result?

Comment: I will try a bit more. Maybe is some driver problem with Robo3T and backward compatibility: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669178/how-to-update-multiple-array-elements-in-mongodb/46054172#46054172. If nothing works, I will open a question. Thank you! :)

Comment: I'm using MongoDB 3.2.0. Apparently this version not supports this kind of operation.

Comment: For me this only modified a single element. If more than one element matched, only the first will be updated

Comment: indeed this only updates first matching nested element. don't know how to allow for multiple matches (updates)

Comment: @chridam thank you for you answer! works amazing to me! 

I need to update my 'name' value with 'name' prop value + apply str_replace if contains some characters. 

So let's say, if the name is AAA_John I need to update it with BBB_John. 
Any idea, how to access name prop and apply this change on it?

Answer (score 8):

You can use $set operator.

```
> db.test.update({"friends.u._id":"eGqDjAjjtYADbuSnn"},{$set:{"friends.$.u.name":"hello"}})
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 1 })
```

Answer (score 0):

Below should work fine as its tested

First check the current value of the array.

```
db.test.findOne({"friends.u.id" : "eGqDjAjjtYADbuSnn"},{"friends.u.name":1})
```

Now fire the update command

```
db.test.update({"friends.u.id" : "eGqDjAjjtYADbuSnn"},{$set:{"friends.$.u.name":"hello"}})
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 1 })
```

Now check the results again to validate the update values

```
db.test.findOne({"friends.u.id" : "eGqDjAjjtYADbuSnn"},{"friends.u.name":1})
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using python, I created this function to generate the new update:

```
def generate_set_to_update_document(field: str, changes: dict) -> dict:
    new_set = {}
    for change in changes.keys():
        new_set[f"{field}.$.{change}"] = changes[change]
    return new_set
```