# Update nested object properties by using object ids

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

Please refer the following data structure that is stored in the database as a single document,

```
{
  "_id": "objectId",
  "names": [
    {
      "_id": "objectId",
      "first_name": "a",
      "is_used": {
        "hr": false,
        "finance": false
      },
      "alt_names": [
        {
          "_id": "objectId",
          "first_name": "b",
          "is_used": {
            "hr": false,
            "finance": false
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

how can we update the `alt_names` `hr: false` to `hr: true` in nested object by using its object id

Comment: Is the object you provided in an array of similarly-structured objects? Or do you have a direct reference to this object?

Comment: Is the `_id` key attached to each item in the `names` list different from the top-level `_id` key?

Comment: yes _id is unique

Comment: Your question asks how to update it by objectId, but your model has multiple ObjectIDs at multiple levels.  Which one are you referring to?

Answer (score 0):

```
const documents = [];
const targetDocumentId = "foo";

const targetDocument = documents.find(document => document._id === targetDocumentId);

const targetNameId = "bar";

const targetName = targetDocument.names.find(name => name._id === targetNameId);

if (targetName) {
  if (targetName.hasOwnProperty("alt_names")) {
    targetName.alt_names.is_used.hr = true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your mongodb version should be at least **3.6**, and code below is what you need.

```
db.collection.update(
    { "names.alt_names._id": "objectId" },
    { $set: { "names.$[].alt_names.$[filter].is_used.hr": true } },
    { arrayFilters: [{ 'filter._id': 'objectId' }] }
);
```

Reference are below.

[Update an object in nested Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34431435/mongodb-update-an-object-in-nested-array)
[MongoDB 3.6: Array Filters](https://thecodebarbarian.com/a-nodejs-perspective-on-mongodb-36-array-filters)
[Positional Operator Matching Nested Arrays](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-831)