# Find and Update nested array element by ID

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have a user model something like this

```
{
     _id:"something",
     email:"abc@gmail.com",
     contacts:[
     {_id:"123",status:"PENDING"},
     {_id:"456",status:"PENDING"},
     {_id:"789",status:"PENDING"}
     ]
}
```

And I have an id of one of the user's contacts "123" and I want to update that specific contact's status from "PENDING" to "SUCCESSFUL". How can I do that?

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34431435/mongodb-update-an-object-in-nested-array

Comment: This question already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26156687/mongoose-find-update-subdocument

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way is with the array identifier [$](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/), like so:

```
db.collection.updateOne({
  email: "abc@gmail.com",
  "contacts._id": "123"
},
{
  "$set": {
    "contacts.$.status": "SUCCESSFUL"
  }
})
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/SEvPk-G9x0O)

The array identifier updates the first element of the array that matches the query.

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collection.updateOne({ _id: "something" }, { contacts: [{ _id: "123", status: "SUCCESSFUL" }] }, function (err, res) {
    
})
```