# Mongo Db query inside array of object and update

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Ok my schema structure is:

```
"labTest" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("56eaab35b5f57f2c1b022b00"),
            "test" : "Blood Test"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("56eaab35b5f57f2c1b022aff"),
            "test" : "Urine Test"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("56eaab35b5f57f2c1b022afe"),
            "test" : "ECG"
        }
    ],
```

Now I have the **id** and **test** field to this schema, I just want to query and add a **status** field inside this schema and make it **1**.

Any help will be very appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Update Multiple Array Elements in mongodb](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669178/how-to-update-multiple-array-elements-in-mongodb)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using commandline very easily. I am considering that your environment is all set. simply type following command in your commandline interface.

```
db.yourschemaname.update({},{$set:{"status":1}},{multi:true});
```