# MongoDB > Adding a new item into an object inside an array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection that looks like this:

```
{
    _id: ...,
    checkins: [
        {
            id: ...,
            createdAt: 1488052032,
            ...
        },
        {
            id: ...,
            createdAt: 1488052032,
            ...
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to add a new element called `created` next to the *id* and *createdAt* attributes (inside checkins, an array of objects). And I want to do it for all the elements that doesn't have this new element.

I know how to check if an object has already an attribute in it, but I am having some problems adding the element. I am using the code below and returns me an error saying: *The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query*.

```
db.profiles.updateMany(
    {},
    {$set: {"checkins.$.created": new Date(0)}}
)
```

Any ideas about what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the update of multiple array subdocuments is not possible as is (check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669178/how-to-update-multiple-array-elements-in-mongodb)), you can match all documents that match at least one subdocument without the `created` field and then update one by one the subdocuments that must be updated :

```
db.profiles.find({
    "checkins": {
        "$elemMatch": { "created": { "$exists": false } }
    }
}).forEach(function(doc) {

    doc.checkins.filter(function(event) {
        return !('created' in event)
    }).forEach(function(event) {

        db.profiles.update({
            "_id": doc._id,
            "checkins": {
                "$elemMatch": { "created": { "$exists": false } }
            }
        }, {
            $set: {
                "checkins.$.created": new Date(0)
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Note that [`elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) is used with [`exists`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) is used to check if field exists. This should fixed your initial error message with your `updateMany` request (but your initial request won't update all your array elements)