# MongoDB: How to remove an object attribute of array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to remove "answers" attribute of the below example.
So It's possible to do so?

```
{
   _id: 1,
   results: [
      { item: "A", score: 5, answers: [ { q: 1, a: 4 }, { q: 2, a: 6 } ] },
      { item: "B", score: 8, answers: [ { q: 1, a: 8 }, { q: 2, a: 9 } ] }
   ]
}
{
   _id: 2,
   results: [
      { item: "C", score: 8, answers: [ { q: 1, a: 8 }, { q: 2, a: 7 } ] },
      { item: "B", score: 4, answers: [ { q: 1, a: 0 }, { q: 2, a: 8 } ] }
   ]
}
```

The expected result:

```
{
   _id: 1,
   results: [
      { item: "A", score: 5 },
      { item: "B", score: 8 }
   ]
}
{
   _id: 2,
   results: [
      { item: "C", score: 8 },
      { item: "B", score: 4 }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669178/how-to-update-multiple-array-elements-in-mongodb with the update operator as `$unset`