# How to find last element in array which matches value and update it?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have docs with the following fields in MongoDB collection:

```
var doc = {
container_id:12,
steps: [
    {
        name:'name1',
    },
    {
        name:'name2',
    }
]
```

}

I need to find all docs which have container_id == 12 and where last 'steps' element matches 'name2' and update it with a new value.

I have tried the following:

```
let findQ = {'container_id': 12, "steps:{$slice:-1}.name": "name2"};
let updateQ = {"$set": {'steps.$.name': "new name3"}};

db.collection(myCollection).update(
  findQ,
  updateQ,
  {multi: true},
  function (err, doc) { ... }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a [`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) condition to the query portion of the statment in order to make sure that the document contains the array match in the **"last"** position. But that's only an "additional" constraint, and the "position" should be obtained from the standard query option of `"steps.name": "name2"`:

So given sample documents:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59c39cf859f55d64d6e30293"),
    "container_id" : 12.0,
    "steps" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "name1"
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "name2"
        }
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59c39d1b59f55d64d6e30294"),
    "container_id" : 12.0,
    "steps" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "name1"
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "name2"
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "name3"
        }
    ]
}
```

Issuing the query:

```
db.collection('junk').update(
  { 
    "container_id": 12,
    "steps.name": "name2",
    "$where": "this.steps.slice(-1)[0].name === 'name2'"
  },
  { "$set": { "steps.$.name": "new name4" } },
  { "multi": true }
)
```

Results in:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59c39cf859f55d64d6e30293"),
    "container_id" : 12.0,
    "steps" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "name1"
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "new name4"
        }
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59c39d1b59f55d64d6e30294"),
    "container_id" : 12.0,
    "steps" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "name1"
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "name2"
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "name3"
        }
    ]
}
```

So the second document though containing an array element with the matching value of `"name2"`, gets excluded by the `$where` clause since it's not the last element in the array.

Only the first document gets updated because it matched both of the conditions.

> **NOTE**: You still need the `"steps.name": "name2"` in the query portion of `.update()` in order to give the position for the [positional `$` operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/). If there are actually more than one match in the array for the same value, then it's not possible to do at this time. [See How to Update Multiple Array Elements in MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669178/how-to-update-multiple-array-elements-in-mongodb/46054172#46054172) for more detail on multiple matches.

Answer (score 0):

According to description as mentioned into above question please try executing following update operation into MongoDB shell.

```
db.myCollection.update({
        "container_id": 12.0,
        steps: {
            $elemMatch: {
                "name": "name2"
            }
        }
    }, {
        $set: {
            'steps.$.name': 'name3'
        }
    }, {
        multi: true
    }


)
```

Comment: Please read  [Specify Multiple Conditions for Array Elements](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-arrays/#specify-multiple-conditions-for-array-elements), then intended usage of `$elemMatch` is for "multiple conditions". This is **one** condition, therefore that part of the OP's question is correct. `$elemMatch` is not a magic bullet. The real point of the question is "matching the last array element: