# mongodb update nested query is not working

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am trying to write a generic query to update the `attempts1` field

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59d659eb9d492019f018cf14"),
    "_class" : "com.anthem.twofatoggleattemptevent.mongo.collections.abc",
    "masterCollection1" : {
        "version" : "1.0",
        "keys" : [ 
            {
                "type" : "test",
                "value" : "636T90012~1985-01-01~Mohan~test"
            }, 
            {
                "type" : "usernm",
                "value" : "~AF99990865"
            }, 
            {
                "type" : "webguid",
                "value" : "25e03606-da67-448a-8ece-881829b95daa"
            }
        ],
        "events" : [ 
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("59d659eb9d492019f018cf13"),
                "eventType" : {
                    "code" : "Test-UAT",
                    "desc" : "Test"
                },
                "eventSrc" : "Toggle_Indvidual",
                "suggestedAction" : "Test",
                "effectiveDt" : ISODate("2017-01-01T05:00:00.000Z"),
                "terminationDt" : Date(253402232400000)
            }, 
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("59d65a1a9d492019f018cf16"),
                "eventType" : {
                    "code" : "Test-UAT",
                    "desc" : "Test"
                },
                "eventSrc" : "Toggle_Indvidual",
                "suggestedAction" : "Test",
                "effectiveDt" : ISODate("2017-01-01T05:00:00.000Z"),
                "terminationDt" : Date(253402232400000)
            }, 
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("59d65ac49d492019f018cf18"),
                "eventType" : {
                    "code" : "Test-UAT",
                    "desc" : "Test"
                },
                "eventSrc" : "Toggle_Indvidual",
                "suggestedAction" : "Test",
                "effectiveDt" : ISODate("2017-01-01T05:00:00.000Z"),
                "terminationDt" : Date(253402232400000)
            }, 
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("59d65b8d9d492019f018cf1a"),
                "eventType" : {
                    "code" : "Test-UAT",
                    "desc" : "Test"
                },
                "eventSrc" : "Toggle_Indvidual",
                "suggestedAction" : "Test",
                "effectiveDt" : ISODate("2017-01-01T05:00:00.000Z"),
                "terminationDt" : Date(253402232400000)
            }, 
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("59d65d309d492019f07817fd"),
                "eventType" : {
                    "code" : "Test-UAT",
                    "desc" : "Test"
                },
                "eventSrc" : "Toggle_Indvidual",
                "suggestedAction" : "Test",
                "effectiveDt" : ISODate("2017-01-01T05:00:00.000Z"),
                "terminationDt" : Date(253402232400000)
            }
        ],
        "attempts1" : [ 
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("59dbbdb2c6700e1b08261059"),
                "type" : "001",
                "desc" : "Defer",
                "count" : 1,
                "srcType" : "Login-contactUpdate"
            }, 
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("59dbc884c6700e1b08b571d4"),
                "type" : "002",
                "desc" : "Confirm",
                "count" : 1,
                "srcType" : "Login-contactUpdate"
            }, 
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("59dbcc8bc6700e1b08b571d7"),
                "type" : "003",
                "desc" : "Update",
                "count" : 1,
                "srcType" : "Login-contactUpdate"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The below query works for me but I want a complete query for this job.

```
update({"masterCollection1" : {$exists: true}},{$set: { "masterCollection1.attempts1.0.type" : "444444" }}, {multi: true }
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to update? The first element in the `attempts1` array? Can you please provide the smallest amount of sample code possible plus your desired result?

Comment: Yes, want update first element of attempts1 means 0.type

Comment: So what exactly is it that you would want to be generic? I don't understand what your question really is...

Comment: Have to write a update query to update data under the attempts1 fields below query is work for me but want proper query .                                                                        update({"masterCollection1" : {$exists: true}},{$set: { "masterCollection1.attempts1.0.type" : "444444" }}, {multi: true }

Comment: What is a "proper" query? What's wrong with this query?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669178/how-to-update-multiple-array-elements-in-mongodb ?

Comment: @dnickless, I feel, the OP wants to update all subdocuments inside attempts1 with value 444444.
At present, he has mentioned as ` { "masterCollection1.attempts1.0.type" : "444444" }`
He wants it to work with mentioning the index i.e `attempts1.0`.