# Using $[<identifier>] query not working with mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to follow the filtered [positional operator $](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/#up._S_[%3Cidentifier%3E]) to update an a field in a target subdocument stored in array like this :

> trainings : [
>           {
>               "title": "bonjour",
>               "category": "clochard",
>               "_id": "5a3bee028e3f660b30382a21"
>           },
>           {
>               "title": "Controlleur",
>               "category": "Métro sahel",
>               "_id": "5a3c0378c52add202218b199"
>           },
>           {
>               "title": "Controlleur",
>               "category": "Métro Tunis",
>               "_id": "5a3c0380c52add202218b19a"
>           },
>           {
>               "title": "Takwira",
>               "category": "sport",
>               "_id": "5a3c038ac52add202218b19b"
>           }
>       ]

This is my query implemented with mongoose (trainings is a field in User model):

```
User.findByIdAndUpdate(user._id, { $set: { "trainings.$[element].content": req.body } },
                 { arrayFilters: [ { "element._id": req.params.courseId } ],upsert: true},function (err, updatedTrainings)
             {
               if (err)
               {
                 console.log(err);
               }
               res.json({success:true,message:"Training updated succfully",body:updatedTrainings});
             });
```

I get this error:

> { MongoError: exception: cannot use the part (trainings of
>   trainings.$[element].content) to traverse the element ({trainings: [ {
>   slugs: [], createdAt: new Date(1513876994108), _id:
>   ObjectId('5a3bee028e3f660b30382a21'), content: { title: "bonjour",
>   category: "clochard" }, path: "bonjour-clochard-664" }, { slugs: [],
>   createdAt: new Date(1513882488053), _id:
>   ObjectId('5a3c0378c52add202218b199'), content: { title: "Controlleur",
>   category: "Métro sahel" }, path: "Controlleur-Métro sahel-505" }, {
>   slugs: [], createdAt: new Date(1513882496517), _id:
>   ObjectId('5a3c0380c52add202218b19a'), content: { title: "Controlleur",
>   category: "Métro Tunis" }, path: "Controlleur-Métro Tunis-887" }, {
>   slugs: [], createdAt: new Date(1513882506039), _id:
>   ObjectId('5a3c038ac52add202218b19b'), content: { title: "Takwira",
>   category: "sport" }, path: "Takwira-sport-833" } ]})
>       at Function.MongoError.create (/home/developer/takwinland/backend/app/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/error.js:31:11)
>       at /home/developer/takwinland/backend/app/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:497:72
>       at authenticateStragglers (/home/developer/takwinland/backend/app/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:443:16)
>       at Connection.messageHandler (/home/developer/takwinland/backend/app/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:477:5)
>       at Socket. (/home/developer/takwinland/backend/app/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:331:22)
>       at emitOne (events.js:125:13)
>       at Socket.emit (events.js:221:7)
>       at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:265:12)
>       at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:252:11)
>       at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:209:10)
>       at TCP.onread (net.js:598:20)

Comment: Can you run db.version() in shell to confirm mongo version ?

Comment: Hello this the version of mongo db :> db.version()
2.6.10

Comment: Multi array updates functionality is available  from 3.6 version

Comment: If I migrate to mongodb 3.6, should I update mongoose version ? the current version is 4.11.12 !

Comment: Array filters are changes on server side. It should work fine but for rest of 3.6 changes you may have to. Not sure if mongoose has a 3.6 compatible release out already. You should get the latest anyways.

Comment: just a last question, Is there anyway to handle this query (update a field of a sub document in an array of sub documents) in earlier versions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Update Multiple Array Elements in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669178/how-to-update-multiple-array-elements-in-mongodb)

Comment: Actually looking at your data it looks like you don't need the multi positional operator. Regular single positional query should  work for you. Try `User.update({_id:user._id, "trainings._id".req.params.courseId"}, { $set: { "trainings.$.content": req.body } },                  {upsert: true}`

Comment: It worked fine and updated the subdocument, but didn't trigger the the update middleware which i defined in the subdoc schema,