# Mongoose update an item from array by id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In a node js project, where I use mongoose, I'm trying to update an item of array inside a document. 
I have a `users` schema which has a `notifications` array inside. Each user has an `_id` and each notifications item has an `_id`.

How can update a notification by, user id and notification id?

**USER SCHEMA:**

```
const schema = mongoose.Schema({
  notifications: [{
    id: { type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId },
    title: { type: String },
    body: { type: String },
    isRead: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    date: { type: Date }
  }],
  token: { type: String },
  isActive: { type: Boolean, default: false }
}, { timestamps: {} })
```

This is what I've tried so far:

```
exports.updateNotification = (req, res) => {

  // Note: in req.params I receive id(for user id) and notificationId.

  UserModel.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, { $set: { notifications: req.body } }, { safe: true, upsert: true, new: true })
    .then((result) => res.status(201).json({
      success: true,
      message: res.__('success.add'),
      user: result
    }))
    .catch(err => errorHandler.handle(err, res))
}
```

The method `findByIdAndUpdate` I've used it to updated the user, but I don't know how to adapt it for updating a notification, by id.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try using `$elemMatch`,

```
UserModel.findOneAndUpdate({_id: 1, notifications: {$elemMatch: {id: 2}}},
                           {$set: {'notifications.$.title': req.body.title,
                                   'notifications.$.body': req.body.body,}}, // list fields you like to change
                           {'new': true, 'safe': true, 'upsert': true});
```

Comment: When I do this way, I get : Mongo Error: The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query. Unexpanded update: notifications.$.title

Comment: Does the element with the `id` you gave exist in your database? I simply gave 2 as a placeholder. It should be `mongoose.Types.ObjectId` type

Comment: Yes, just rechecked 3rd time :)

Comment: Can you show me the object you are trying to query.

Comment: Yes. Here is the object: https://ibb.co/fLRmJ7 and here is the query: https://ibb.co/fO4dWS and here you have the code: https://ibb.co/g0F7Qn

Comment: and I console log before the id's to recheck, they arrives good in the function...

Comment: Hey, what is contained in `req.params.notificationId`, I suspect it is a `string`, Try changing it to `new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.notificationId)`

Comment: And also, the `notifications` objects have `_id` field not `id`.

Comment: the last comment solved the problem. `notifications._id`. By the way it works with both ways `elemMatch` or without. I choose the simplest. https://ibb.co/jzVGkn Thank you very much!

Comment: The `dot` and `$elemMatch` are not the same. The `dot` notation will return any of the array entries satisfy any of the condition, more like `or`. `$elemMatch` will return only documents which satisfy all the conditions. In your case since its only a single condition, it worked out. Try multiple conditions, it will not always return right ones. Use `$elemMatch`

Comment: Thx. Do you know if there is something to update the provided fields? For the moment I've created a function to construct the $set object, but maybe there is something native, already... (https://ibb.co/fuQoy7)

Comment: native to do something like your `bindFieldsToUpdate`  function does. AFAIK, nothing like that.

Comment: Please can you explain that what is the `safe: true` and `upsert: true` for?

Comment: safe will get us if any errors happened on mongodb to our callback, and upsert is for if document exists update it or if does not insert a new one.

Comment: Suppose there is 10 object in the array. Now I want to update the title field of id 4,5,6 at once. So, how can we do that because you are updating only one record? Can we update the record based on the array?

Comment: I think the answer in this link gives you want you looking for: [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669178/how-to-update-multiple-array-elements-in-mongodb#answer-46054172)

Answer (score 4):

```
UserModel.update({'_id':1,'notifications.id': 2}, {'$set': {
    'notifications.$.title': 'updated title',
    'notifications.$.body': 'updated body'
}}, function(err) { ...}
```

Haven't tested but this should work.

Comment: Thank you, I'll check and let you know!

Comment: It sais it is successfully updated, but there is no change in the db :-| I tried with `update` and `findOneAndUpdate` but none works...

Comment: I tried this: 
  UserModel.update(
    { _id: req.params.id, 'notifications.id': req.params.notificationId },
    { $set: { 'notifications.$.title': 'baubau' } },
    { new: true })
    .then((result) => res.status(202).json({
      success: true,
      message: res.__('success.update'),
      res: result
    }))
    .catch(err => errorHandler.handle(err, res))

Comment: Suppose there is 10 object in the array. Now I want to update the title field of id 4,5,6 at once. So, how can we do that because you are updating only one record? Can we update the record based on the array?