# MongoDB update Query in a loop

Tags: mongodb

I am working with MongoDB in one of my project. For the next feature I need to add a flag to array of objects by looping with a matching condition.

Following is an example of document that I have -

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5aaa4eb211a1c1c1f74c1657"),
    "colors" : [
       { "status" : "done" },
       { "status" : "done" },
       { "status" : "n/a" }
   ]        
}
```

Output should be -

```
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("5aaa4eb211a1c1c1f74c1657"),
   "colors" : [
       {
           "status" : "done",
           "is_in_production" : true
       }, 
       {
           "status" : "done",
           "is_in_production" : true
       },
       {
        "status" : "n/a"
       }
   ]
}
```

I used the following query -

```
db.getCollection('products').update( 
   {
       "colors.status": {
          "$in":[
             "done"
          ]
       }
   },
   {$set: { 'colors.$[].is_in_production' :true }},
   {multi: true}
)
```

That resulted the following error -

```
cannot use the part(colors of colors.$[].is_in_production)totraversetheelement({ colors: [{ "status" : "done" }, { "status" : "done" }, { "status" : "n/a" }] )}
```

Can someone help me with the query?? Thanks in Advance

Comment: First of all, please check your Mongo version. I ran your query on my local (MongoDB 3.6.3) and I see results: 1) https://i.stack.imgur.com/6dfMi.png 2) https://i.stack.imgur.com/DbMta.png , So your query is wrong.

Comment: Mate, the result that you have, shows all the objects with colors array with "is_in_production" : true. I want the flag to be added only for the objects with "status" : "done". And I am using MongoDB shell version v3.4.7

Comment: Thats what I said `your query is wrong`

Comment: You need to upgrade your version and I have updated your query in the below answer. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

Use [updateMany](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/) together with [arrayFilters](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/#specify-arrayfilters-for-an-array-update-operations) to update multiple documents in an array

```
db.products.updateMany(
   { "colors.status": "done" },
   { $set: { "colors.$[element].is_in_production" : true}},
   { arrayFilters: [{"element.status" : "done"}]}
)
```

Comment: OP is asking if an alternate method is available other than `arrayFlter` since it has tight dependency on v3.6. OP is using v3.4 and he says it may be a risk upgrading to higher version.

Comment: This post has a lot of other options than arrayFilters please have a look into it - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669178/how-to-update-multiple-array-elements-in-mongodb

Comment: Positional operators  `$[]` are giving incorrect results and that's why left with `arrayFilters`

Comment: I copied the DB in test server, and it worked. Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 1):

Use `arrayFilters` to update only a subset of embedded documents.

Try this query:

```
db.products.update(
{
   "colors.status": {
      "$in":[
         "done"
        ]
     }
  },
  {$set: { 'colors.$[element].is_in_production' :true }},
  {multi: true, arrayFilters:[{"element.status":"done"}]}
)
```

Output is:

```
/* 1 */
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5aaa4eb211a1c1c1f74c1657"),
"colors" : [ 
    {
        "status" : "done",
        "is_in_production" : true
    }, 
    {
        "status" : "done",
        "is_in_production" : true
    }, 
    {
        "status" : "n/a"
    }
  ]
}
```

[image]

Note that you need MongoDB 3.6 and need to execute on latest shell (no third party tools preferably) in order for the `arrayFilters` to work properly.

If the above query isn't working for your Mongo version, try this query:

```
db.sample.findAndModify({
  query:{
     "colors.status": {
        "$in":[
           "done"
        ]
     }
 },
 update:{$set: { 'colors.$[element].is_in_production' : true }},
 multi: true, 
 arrayFilters:[{"element.status":"done"}]
})
```

Comment: Any other way to rewrite the same query?? I am running MongoDb on Docker. It will take a lot of time to upgrade. Or might break other container :(

Comment: Updated the answer with an alternate query. Hope that helps! But I still suspect `arrayFilter` part may not work since there are some updates to `findAndModify` on v3.6

Comment: Also note that your previous query on positional operators `$[]` , is not working (Forget the fact that it was wrong). Its because of  version issues. The issues you were facing were already reported in the past by users and thats why they have fixed them in latest version along with lots of features.

Comment: I copied the DB in test server, and it worked. Thanks for your help!!