# update double-nested collection in mongodb

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-mongo

I have a Java entity `PostsHolder` wchich in MongoDB looks like this:

```
{
   "id":"1",
   "name": "xxx"
   "posts":[
      {
         "_id":"1",
         "inner":{
            "value":"value1",
            "type":"typeX",
         }
      },
      {
         "_id":"2",
         "inner":{
            "value":"value2",
            "type":"type1",
         }
      },
      {
         "_id":"3",
         "inner":{
            "value":"value2",
            "type":"typeX",
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

I want to update every `post` `value` field if `type == 'typeX'`.

How can I do this?

I've tried the below code but it changes only the first occurence in `posts` collection:

```
    WriteResult wr = mongoTemplate.updateMulti(
        new Query(where("posts.inner.type").is("typeX")),
        new Update().set("posts.$.inner.value", "changedValue"),
        PostHolder.class,
        "post_holder"
    );
```

Comment: Which version of MongoDB are you using?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669178/how-to-update-multiple-array-elements-in-mongodb

Comment: I am using mongo 3.4.3