# Mongodb: Aggregation/Pipilines to join two schema's data based on nested documents

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework, nested-documents

Here is my schema:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var EventSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {type:String},
    start_date: {type:Date},
    duration: {type:String},
    event_id:{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId}
});
var Project = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String, 
        required: '{PATH} is required!'
    },
    user_id:{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required:'{PATH} is required!'
    },
    client: {type: Object},
    no_of_events: {type: String, required: '{PATH} is required!'},
    start_date:{type:Date, required: '{PATH} is required!'},
    end_date:{type:Date, required: '{PATH} is required!'},
    budget:{type: String},
    groom:{type:Object},
    bride:{type:Object},
    events:[EventSchema],
    status:{type:Number,Default:1}, //0=Inactive, 1=Active, 2=Completed
    created_at: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    updated_at: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Project', Project);
```

While creating Project, I am adding multiple events. Therefore in 'events' there is array of objects. Here is the sample data:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5b43582a716d9a4e96345f4a"
    },
    "bride": {
        "city": "Hyderabad",
        "phone": "09876543211",
        "dob": "1993-05-06T18:30:00.000Z",
        "name": "Shriya Bhupal"
    },
    "groom": {
        "city": "Hyderabad",
        "phone": "09876543211",
        "dob": "1993-08-09T18:30:00.000Z",
        "name": "Anindith Reddy"
    },
    "client": {
        "name": "Apoorva Pagar"
    },
    "end_date": {
        "$date": "2018-07-22T18:30:00.000Z"
    },
    "start_date": {
        "$date": "2018-07-10T18:30:00.000Z"
    },
    "no_of_events": "4",
    "user_id": {
        "$oid": "5b126966bcc8072e526346ad"
    },
    "name": "Big Fat Wedding",
    "updated_at": {
        "$date": "2018-07-09T12:42:18.263Z"
    },
    "created_at": {
        "$date": "2018-07-09T12:42:18.263Z"
    },
    "events": [
        {
            "name": "Engagement",
            "event_id": {
                "$oid": "5b3b232914cdec23c19c034c"
            },
            "start_date": {
                "$date": "2018-07-11T18:30:00.000Z"
            },
            "duration": "1 Day",
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "5b43582a716d9a4e96345f4b"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Mehndi",
            "event_id": {
                "$oid": "5b3b23b314cdec23c19c034d"
            },
            "start_date": {
                "$date": "2018-07-12T18:30:00.000Z"
            },
            "duration": "1 Day",
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "5b43582a716d9a4e96345f4c"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Sangeet",
            "event_id": {
                "$oid": "5b3b232914cdec23c19c034c"
            },
            "start_date": {
                "$date": "2018-07-17T18:30:00.000Z"
            },
            "duration": "2 Days",
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "5b43582a716d9a4e96345f4d"
            }
        }
    ],
    "__v": 0
}
```

Here the case is, If I add event from the default events, then there is event_id, otherwise there is no event_id. So if I added, default events that are saved in another schema called 'defaultevents'. Now I want to add eventdetail in each event object if event_id exists in data.

```
    {"events": [
            {
// it should include event_detail:{ details about event from defaultevents}
                "name": "Engagement",
                "event_id": {
                    "$oid": "5b3b232914cdec23c19c034c"
                },
                "start_date": {
                    "$date": "2018-07-11T18:30:00.000Z"
                },
                "duration": "1 Day",
                "_id": {
                    "$oid": "5b43582a716d9a4e96345f4b"
                }
            },
            {
// it should not include event_details as there is no event_id
                "name": "Mehndi",
                "start_date": {
                    "$date": "2018-07-12T18:30:00.000Z"
                },
                "duration": "1 Day",
                "_id": {
                    "$oid": "5b43582a716d9a4e96345f4c"
                }
            }
    ]
    }
```

DefaultEvents Sameple Data:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5b3b232914cdec23c19c034c"
    },
    "image": "https://dostbucket.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/events/1530601666360mehndi.svg",
    "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
    "name": "Sangeet",
    "updated_at": {
        "$date": "2018-07-03T07:18:01.166Z"
    },
    "created_at": {
        "$date": "2018-07-03T07:18:01.166Z"
    },
    "__v": 0
}
```

mongod version: 3.4.7 (MMAPv1)

Comment: Please post the sample collection for `defaultevents` schema and also which version of mongodb you are using/

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet jsut added the sample data for Default Events and mongoose version. Hope that helps

Comment: I think question here is to update the Product Document to have **event_details** field if they have **event_id** in events array? correct? Please update the question accordingly.

Comment: I don't want to save event_details in the document but need this join to render the data @Jack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below aggregation in 3.6.

```
ProjectModel.aggregate([
  {"$unwind":"$events"},
  {"$lookup":{
    "from": "event", //name of the foreign collection not model or schema name
    "localField": "events.event_id",
    "foreignField": "_id",
    "as": "events.eventdetail"
  }},
  {"$unwind":{"path":"$events.eventdetail", "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays":true }}, // Keep non matching events
  {"$group":{
    "_id": "$_id",
    "events": { "$push": "$events" },
    "data": { "$first": "$$ROOT" } // $$ROOT to keep the entire data
  }},
  {"$addFields":{"data.events":"$events", "events":0}}, // Replace the events  with grouped events.
  {"$replaceRoot":{"newRoot":"$data"}}
])
```

Comment: Will you please tell me the use of $unwind? I read the documentation too but doesn't understand. @Veeram

Comment: `$unwind` converts array [] into documents {}. We unwind to convert events array into documents for lookup stage. Again, as lookup returns array we convert the returned array back to documents.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) aggregation

```
db.colletion.aggregate([
  { "$unwind": "$events" },
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": DefaultEventSchema.collection.name,
    "localField": "events.event_id",
    "foreignField": "_id",
    "as": "events.event_id"
  }},
  { "$unwind": { "path": "$events.event_id", "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true } },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id",
    "events": { "$push": "$events" },
    "bride": { "$first": "$bride" },
    "groom": { "$first": "$groom" },
    "client": { "$first": "$client" },
    "end_date": { "$first": "$end_date" },
    "no_of_events": { "$first": "$no_of_events" },
    "name": { "$first": "$name" },
    "created_at": { "$first": "$created_at" },
    "updated_at": { "$first": "$updated_at" }
  }}
])
```

Comment: It doesn't return other fields of the schema. Also, it doesn't return anything if there is no event id

Comment: Question changed?

Comment: No, It returns: {
            "_id": "5b3c8e6d6283e24f522adaef",
            "events": [
                [],
                [],
                []
            ],
            "otherFields": null
        } if event_id not exists

Comment: Check the updated answer... If your both the localField and foreignField are same then it should work... And also your collection name i.e. (`DefaultEventSchema.collection.name`) should be correct...

Comment: Why you are replacing events.event_id? I want to have data from events objects as well as from another schema as detail

Comment: I just made a change please try it again and if not then please show how your data looks like

Comment: This works well but it doesn't return events for which event_id do not exist. Kindly check my question again. I want all events. If event_id exists then with event_detail otherwise events.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176238/discussion-between-simerjit-parmar-and-anthony-winzlet).

Answer (score 0):

Simerjit, as mongo does not provide $ (positioning operator) to search and update on the array of objects (If we try to do it only first object gets updated [read more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669178/how-to-update-multiple-array-elements-in-mongodb)), we would need to do it in following way:

```
var products = Product.find();

products.forEach(product => {
    product.events.forEach(event => {
        if ('event_id' in event) {
            var product = product.events[event];
            product.event.event_details = 'my details';
            product.save(product);
        }
    });
});
```

You might need to make some tweaks to the code, but I hope it gives you the idea how you can achieve what you are looking for.

Comment: I don't want to save the details in the document. I want these details to render the data  in the front-end.