# Remove field found in any mongodb array

Tags: mongodb

I have a document looking like this:

```
{
field: 'value',
field2: 'value',
scan: [
    [
        {
            dontDeleteMe: 'keepMe',
            arrayToDelete: [0,1,2]
        },
        {
            dontDeleteMe: 'keepMe',
            arrayToDelete: [0,1,2]
        },
        {
            dontDeleteMe: 'keepMe',
            arrayToDelete: [0,1,2]
        },
        {
            dontDeleteMe: 'keepMe',
            arrayToDelete: [0,1,2]
        },
    ],
    [
        {
            dontDeleteMe: 'keepMe',
            arrayToDelete: [0,1,2]
        },
        {
            dontDeleteMe: 'keepMe',
            arrayToDelete: [0,1,2]
        },
        {
            dontDeleteMe: 'keepMe',
            arrayToDelete: [0,1,2]
        },
        {
            dontDeleteMe: 'keepMe',
            arrayToDelete: [0,1,2]
        },
    ],
    [
        {
            dontDeleteMe: 'keepMe',
            arrayToDelete: [0,1,2]
        },
        {
            dontDeleteMe: 'keepMe',
            arrayToDelete: [0,1,2]
        },
        {
            dontDeleteMe: 'keepMe',
            arrayToDelete: [0,1,2]
        },
        {
            dontDeleteMe: 'keepMe',
            arrayToDelete: [0,1,2]
        },
    ],

]

}
```

We only want to delete any instance of the arrayToDelete that is in a dictionary nested in a list of lists in "scan".

Currently, I've been using

```
 update({}, {$unset: {"scans.0.0.arrayToDelete":1}}, {multi: true})
```

to delete the array. However, this only deletes the first `(0.0)` as you would imagine.

Is it possible to iterate over the scan array and the nested array to delete "arrayToDelete", and keep all other fields?

Thanks

Comment: That's not a valid data structure. You cannot have index values presented like that directly within the `[]` elements. I suggest you use the `mongo` shell to retrieve and represent what your data actually looks like. I'm just going to presume it's actually like `{ scan: [[{  arrayToDelete: [0,1,2]  },{  arrayToDelete: [0,1,2]  }],[{  arrayToDelete: [0,1,2]  },{  arrayToDelete: [0,1,2]  },],...] }` But you really should correct it here to how it actually looks.

Comment: Thanks Neil, I've corrected the structure

Comment: Change update to UpdateMany() and check

Comment: So is there anything else actually in the array that needs to stay there? Or can `"scan"` basically be set to `[]`? Because that would be the shortest path? If not that, then do you mean **remove the array element** that contains the `arrayToDelete`? Or do you just want to remove that named field from within the object inside the array, and inside the other array? That could be made clearer.

Comment: @NeilLunn I've updated the q. to make it more clear. We only want to delete any instance of the arrayToDelete that is in a dictionary nested in a list of lists in "scan".

Comment: @Priyank That didn't seem to work - using the code in the question it will only delete the first dictionary in the first list, for each document in the db.

Comment: @Dave I kind of could not wait and included something similar to your edit in my answer. Also answered a couple of different cases there, so your actual question appears to be **Case 2**. But now at least you have the others for reference of what to do for those as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I asked a question in the comments but you seem to have walked away, so I guess I just answer the three possible cases I see.

To begin with, I'm not certain if the elements shown within the nested arrays are the ***only*** elements within the array or in fact if `arrayToDelete` is the ***only*** field present in those elements. So basically I need to *abstract* a little and include that case:

```
{
    field: 'value',
    field2: 'value',
    scan: [
        [
            {
                arrayToDelete: [0,1,2],
                anotherField: "a"
            },
            {   somethingToKeep: 1 },
            {
                arrayToDelete: [0,1,2],
                anotherField: "a"
            },
            {
                arrayToDelete: [0,1,2],
                anotherField: "a"
            },
            {
                arrayToDelete: [0,1,2],
                anotherField: "a"
            },
        ],
        [
            {
                arrayToDelete: [0,1,2],
                anotherField: "a"
            },
            {
                arrayToDelete: [0,1,2],
                anotherField: "a"
            },
            {
                arrayToDelete: [0,1,2],
                anotherField: "a"
            },
            {   somethingToKeep: 1 },
            {
                arrayToDelete: [0,1,2],
                anotherField: "a"
            },
        ],
        [
            {   somethingToKeep: 1 },
            {
                arrayToDelete: [0,1,2],
                anotherField: "a"
            },
            {
                arrayToDelete: [0,1,2],
                anotherField: "a"
            },
            {
                arrayToDelete: [0,1,2],
                anotherField: "a"
            },
            {
                arrayToDelete: [0,1,2],
                anotherField: "a"
            },
        ],
    ]
}
```

### Case 1 - Remove the inner array elements where the Field is present

This would use the [`$pull`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) operator since that is what *removes array elements* entirely. You do this in modern MongoDB with a statement like this:

```
db.collection.updateMany(
  { "scan": {
    "$elemMatch": {
      "$elemMatch": {
        "arrayToDelete": { "$exists": true }
      }
    }
  } },
  {
    "$pull": {
      "scan.$[a]": { "arrayToDelete": { "$exists": true } }
    }
  },
  { "arrayFilters": [
      {  "a": { "$elemMatch": { "arrayToDelete": { "$exists": true } } } }
    ]
  }
)
```

That alters all matching documents like this:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ca1c36d9e31550a618011e2"),
        "field" : "value",
        "field2" : "value",
        "scan" : [
                [
                        {
                                "somethingToKeep" : 1
                        }
                ],
                [
                        {
                                "somethingToKeep" : 1
                        }
                ],
                [
                        {
                                "somethingToKeep" : 1
                        }
                ]
        ]
}
```

So every element that contained that field is now removed.

### Case 2 - Just remove the matched field from the inner elements

This is where you use [`$unset`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/). It's just a little different to the *"hard indexed"* version you were doing:

```
db.collection.updateMany(
  { "scan": {
    "$elemMatch": {
      "$elemMatch": {
        "arrayToDelete": { "$exists": true }
      }
    }
  } },
  { "$unset": { "scan.$[].$[].arrayToDelete": ""  } }
)
```

Which alters all matched documents to be:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ca1c4c49e31550a618011e3"),
        "field" : "value",
        "field2" : "value",
        "scan" : [
                [
                        {
                                "anotherField" : "a"
                        },
                        {
                                "somethingToKeep" : 1
                        },
                        {
                                "anotherField" : "a"
                        },
                        {
                                "anotherField" : "a"
                        },
                        {
                                "anotherField" : "a"
                        }
                ],
                [
                        {
                                "anotherField" : "a"
                        },
                        {
                                "anotherField" : "a"
                        },
                        {
                                "anotherField" : "a"
                        },
                        {
                                "somethingToKeep" : 1
                        },
                        {
                                "anotherField" : "a"
                        }
                ],
                [
                        {
                                "somethingToKeep" : 1
                        },
                        {
                                "anotherField" : "a"
                        },
                        {
                                "anotherField" : "a"
                        },
                        {
                                "anotherField" : "a"
                        },
                        {
                                "anotherField" : "a"
                        }
                ]
        ]
}
```

So everything is still there, but just the identified fields have been removed from each inner array document.

### Case 3 - You Actually wanted to remove "Everything" in the array.

Which is really just a simple case of using [`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) and wiping everything that was there before:

```
db.collection.updateMany(
  { "scan": {
    "$elemMatch": {
      "$elemMatch": {
        "arrayToDelete": { "$exists": true }
      }
    }
  } },
  { "$set": { "scan": []  } }
)
```

Where the results should pretty well be expected:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ca1c5c59e31550a618011e4"),
        "field" : "value",
        "field2" : "value",
        "scan" : [ ]
}
```

### So what are these all doing?

The very first thing you should see is the *query predicate*. This is generally a good idea to make sure you are not matching and even *"attempting"* to have update conditions met on documents which do not even contain data with the pattern you are intending to update. Nested arrays are *difficult* at best, and where practical you really should avoid them, as what you often *"really mean"* is actually represented in a singular array with additional attributes representing what you *"think"* the *nesting* is actually doing for you.

But just because they are *hard* does not mean *impossible*. It's just that you need to understand [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/):

```
db.colelction.find(
  { "scan": {
    "$elemMatch": {
      "$elemMatch": {
        "arrayToDelete": { "$exists": true }
      }
    }
  }}
)
```

That's the basic `find()` example, which matches based on the [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) condition for the **outer** array uses another [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) in order to match another condition in the **inner** array. Even though this *"appears"* to be a singular predicate. Something like:

```
"scan.arrayToDelete": { "$exists": true }
```

Just will not work. Neither would:

```
"scan..arrayToDelete": { "$exists": true }
```

With the "double dot" `..` because that's basically just not valid.

That's the *query predicate* to match "documents" that need to be processed, but the rest applies to actually determine *what parts to update".

In the **Case 1** in order to [`$pull`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) from the **inner** array, we first need to be able to identify which elements of the **outer** array contain the data to update. That's what the `"scan.$[a]"` thing is doing using the [positional filtered `$[<identifier>]`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/) operator.

That operator basically *transposes* the matched *indices* ( so *many* of them ) in the array to another *predicate* which is defined in the third section of the `update` style commands with the `arrayFilters` section. This section basically defines the conditions to be met from the perspective of the named identifier.

In this case out "identifier" is named `a`, and that is the prefix used in the `arrayFilters` entry:

```
  { "arrayFilters": [
      {  "a": { "$elemMatch": { "arrayToDelete": { "$exists": true } } } }
    ]
  }
```

Taken in context with the actual *update statement* part:

```
  {
    "$pull": {
      "scan.$[a]": { "arrayToDelete": { "$exists": true } }
    }
  },
```

Then from the perspective of the `"a"` being the identifier for the **outer** array element first inward from `"scan"`, then same conditions apply as for the original *query predicate* but from *"within"* the **first** [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) statement. So you can basically think of this as a "query within a query" from the perspective of already *"looking inside"* the content of **each outer** element.

By the same token the [`$pull`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) acts much like a *"query within a query"* in that it's own arguments are also applied from the perspective of the element of the array. Therefore just the `arrayToDelete` field existing instead of:

```
  // This would be wrong! and do nothing :(
  {
    "$pull": {
      "scan.$[a]": { "$elemMatch": { "arrayToDelete": { "$exists": true } } }
    }
  }
```

But that's all specific to [`$pull`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/), and other things have different cases:

The **Case 2** looks at where you want to just [`$unset`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/) the named field. Seems pretty easy as you just name the field, right? Well not exactly since the following is clearly not right from what we know earlier:

```
  { "$unset": { "scan.arrayToDelete": ""  } } // Not right :(
```

And of course noting array indexes for everything is just a pain:

```
  { "$unset": { 
    "scan.0.0.arrayToDelete": "",
    "scan.0.1.arrayToDelete": "",
    "scan.0.2.arrayToDelete": "",
    "scan.0.3.arrayToDelete": "",  // My fingers are tired :-<
  } }
```

This is the reason for the [positional all `$[]`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/) operator. This one is a little more *"brute force"* than the [positional filtered `$[<identifier>]`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/) in that instead of matching another *predicate* provided within `arrayFilters`, what this simply does is apply to ***everything*** within the array contents at that "index". It's basically a way of in fact saying **"all indexes"** without typing every single one out like the *horrible* case shown above.

So it's not for *all cases*, but it's certainly well suited to an [`$unset`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/) since that has a very specific *path naming* which does not matter of course if that path does not match every single element of the array.

You *could* still use an `arrayFilters` and a [positional filtered `$[<identifier>]`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/), but here it would be overkill. Plus it does not hurt to demonstrate the other approach.

But of course it probably is worth understanding *how* exactly that statement would look, so:

```
db.collection.updateMany(
  { "scan": {
    "$elemMatch": {
      "$elemMatch": {
        "arrayToDelete": { "$exists": true }
      }
    }
  } },
  { "$unset": { "scan.$[a].$[b].arrayToDelete": ""  } },
  {
    "arrayFilters": [
      { "a": { "$elemMatch": { "arrayToDelete": { "$exists": true } } } },
      { "b.arrayToDelete": { "$exists": true } },
    ]
  }
)
```

Noting there that the `"b.arrayToDelete"` may not be what you expect at first, but given the positioning in `"scan.$[a].$[b]` it really should make sense as from the `b` the element name would be reached via "dot notation" just as shown. And in fact in both cases. Yet again, an [`$unset`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/) would only apply to the named field anyway, so the selection criteria really is not required.

And **Case 3**. Well it's quite simple in that if you don't **need** to keep anything else in the array after removing this content ( ie a [`$pull`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) where fields matching this were the **only** things in there, or an [`$unset`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/) for that matter ), then simply don't mess around with anything else and just *wipe the array*.

This is an important distinction if you consider that as per the point to clarify whether the documents with the named field where the ***only*** elements within the nested arrays, and indeed that the named key was the ***only*** thing present in the documents.

With the reasoning being that using [`$pull`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) as shown here and under those conditions you would get:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ca321909e31550a618011e6"),
        "field" : "value",
        "field2" : "value",
        "scan" : [
            [ ],
            [ ],
            [ ]
        ]
}
```

Or with the [`$unset`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/):

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ca322bc9e31550a618011e7"),
        "field" : "value",
        "field2" : "value",
        "scan" : [
            [{ }, { }, { }, { }],
            [{ }, { }, { }, { }],
            [{ }, { }, { }, { }]
        ]
}
```

Both of which are clearly not desirable. So it stands yo reason if the `arrayToDelete` field was the ***only*** content that was in there at all, then the most logical way to *remove all* is simply to replace the array with an empty one. Or indeed [`$unset`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/) the whole document property.

Note however that all these *"fancy things"* ( with the exception of the [`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) of course ) require that you **must have MongoDB 3.6 at least** available in order to use this functionality.

In the event you are still running an older version MongoDB than that ( and as of the date of writing, you really should not be since your official support runs out in just 5 months from this date ) then other existing answers on [How to Update Multiple Array Elements in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669178/how-to-update-multiple-array-elements-in-mongodb) are actually for you.

Comment: Great answer! Thanks Neil, this was super informative. Really appreciate you going through $elemMatch and $pull in detail. Case two is what I was looking for, and the other cases were helpful to know what I'm doing. Many thanks!

Comment: @Dave That's okay as `$elemMatch` in particular can be a bit difficult at first to understand where and where not to use it. In your case here you *"technically"* would not *need* it given how `$unset` applies. But as I said in the content, it would be the difference between processing *every document* instead of just those which actually met the same conditions of containing the fields you actually want to update. So *query predicates* are a good thing for almost every case. As an exercise you might want to look at the exact `arrayFilters` to apply in order to only touch elements that match.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried with your given sample document and its working , you have to use `$[]` to achieve this :

```
db.collectionName.(update({},{$unset: {
   "scan.$[].$[].arrayToDelete": 1
}})
```