# Mongodb how to update more than one array documents

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb, updates

Can somebody tell me please how to update more than one element in array?
I have object like:

```
{
    _id: 1,
    name: 'x',
    someArray: [
        {'a': 1},
        {'a': 1, 'b': 2},
        {'a': 2}
    ]
}
```

I would like to update all elements in **someArray where 'a' == 1**. 
I tried to do it via command

```
db.collection.update(
    {_id: 1, 'somaArray.a': 1}, 
    {$set: {'someArray.$.c': 3}}, 
    {multi: true}
)
```

but this command updated **only one element in someArray**. The second one is not updated. Result seems like:

```
{
    _id: 1,
    name: 'x',
    someArray: [
        {'a': 1, 'c': 3},
        {'a': 1, 'b': 2},
        {'a': 2}
    ]
}
```

How to achieve update of all elements which match the condition?
Thank you.

Comment: Are you using nodejs?

Comment: No, its PHP aplication.

Comment: i think this question is similar to yours visit <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669178/how-to-update-multiple-array-elements-in-mongodb>?

Answer (score 1):

Try as below: [(Read)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/#up._S_[%3Cidentifier%3E])

```
db.collection.update({_id:1},
    {
        $set: {
            'someArray.$[elem].c': 3 
        }        
    },
    { arrayFilters: [{ "elem.a": 1 }], multi: true, "upsert": true }
)
```

Result response will be as below:

```
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "name" : "x",
    "someArray" : [
        {
            "a" : 1,
            "c" : 3
        },
        {
            "a" : 1,
            "b" : 2,
            "c" : 3
        },
        {
            "a" : 2
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Yes but I am on Mongodb 3.4. [elem] does not work in this version.

Answer (score 0):

i think this question is similar to yours

visit ([How to Update Multiple Array Elements in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669178/how-to-update-multiple-array-elements-in-mongodb))! and check it out