# Mongodb Update Elements from Multiple Arrays on a Document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'd like to update a property from objects located in multiple lists on a MongoDB collection's document.

In a MongoDB collection I have documents like this one:

```
{
    "firstArray": [
        {
        "name": "john",
        "updated": false // I wanna switch that to true
        },
        {
        "name": "bob",
        "updated": false
        }
    ],
    "secondArray": [
        {
        "name": "eric",
        "updated": false
        },
        {
        "name": "john",
        "updated": false // I wanna switch that to true
        }
    ]
}
```

My goal is to update every element with `"name":"john"` from document's properties `firstArray` and `secondArray` to `updated:true`.

As they can be parallel accesses to a document, I shall only use [update operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/#id1) (a read and replace method [like that one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20601288/4973023) would add the risk of dropping changes made by another process)

It looks like the [filtered positional operator $[]](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/) as mentioned in [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46054172/4973023) is the way to go to update an object's property from a document's Array **BUT** it appears that *it doesn't support multiple `$set` with the same operator* nor *using two operators (one by array) in two different `$set`*!

As this mongo shell command only update the `secondArray`:

```
    db['collection'].update(
    {},
    {
        "$set": { "firstArray.$[elem].updated": true },
        "$set": { "secondArray.$[elem].updated": true }
    },
    { "arrayFilters": [{ "elem.name": "john" }], "multi": true })
```

And this command returns `The array filter for identifier 'a' was not used in the update { $set: { secondArray.$[b].updated: true } }`:

```
    db['collection'].update(
    {},
    {
        "$set": { "firstArray.$[a].updated": true },
        "$set": { "secondArray.$[b].updated": true }
    },
    { "arrayFilters": [{ "a.name": "john" }, { "b.name": "john" }], "multi": true })
```

So, would you have any idea how to do that update? (Bonus point for any documentation quotes about the above limitations )

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second argument to that function in an object.  A given field name can only have one value in an object.  To show what is being sent to the server, I assigned the value you are using to a variable:

```
> var o={    
     "$set": { "firstArray.$[a].updated": true },         
     "$set": { "secondArray.$[b].updated": true }     
}; 
> printjson(o)
{ "$set" : { "secondArray.$[b].updated" : true } }
```

As you can see, the first value was overwritten by the second because both fields were named `$set`.

Try combining these into a single field:

```
{
  "$set": { 
           "firstArray.$[elem].updated": true,
            "secondArray.$[elem].updated": true 
  }
}
```

Comment: How did I missed that? Thanks a bunch Joe!

Comment: I guess I misread the doc as [this update example](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#perform-conditional-updates-based-on-current-field-values) mentions two different `$set` (for a reason though) but [the actual page](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) for the `$set` operator clearly mention example to update different properties with a single use.