# How update any matching in array multiple times in multiple documents on Mongoose model and not only first?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, mongodb, mongoose

So I have a model of Chat.

```
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const chatSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    id              : {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
    email1          : String,
    email2          : String,
    avasrc1         : String,
    avasrc2         : String,
    lastMessage     : String,
    lastMsgTime     : String,
    messages        : [{email: String, name: String, avasrc: String, msg: String, msgTime: String}]
});
```

And in server I want to change avatar sources to  if email match email.
So I tried...

```
await Chat.update({email1: email}, {$set: {avasrc1: avatar}}, {multi: true})
await Chat.update({email2: email}, {$set: {avasrc2: avatar}}, {multi: true})
await Chat.update({messages: {$elemMatch:{email: email}}},{"$set": {"messages.$.avasrc": avatar}}, {multi: true})
```

In a result it works only for first one. I need to change:

1. **All avasrc1 to avatar if email1 = email**
2. **All avasrc2 to avatar if email2 = email**
3. **All messages.avasrc in whole array to  if messages.email = email**

Comment: Try this query if works:-
    db.Chat.update({email1: email}, {$set: {avasrc1: avatar}}, false, true);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer for my question by reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46054172/9847896) for another question.

Final answer for this is.

```
await Chat.updateMany({email1: email}, {$set: {avasrc1: avatar}}, {multi: true})
await Chat.updateMany({email2: email}, {$set: {avasrc2: avatar}}, {multi: true})
await Chat.updateMany({"messages.email": email},{"$set": {"messages.$[elem].avasrc": avatar}}, { "arrayFilters": [{ "elem.email": email }], "multi": true })
```

Thanks for help, hope the answer will help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use multiple query for same collection. You can use one query like this,

```
await Chat.updateMany({email1: email}, {$set: {avasrc1: avatar, avasrc2: avatar}})
```

Check this documentation for further detail,
[update many mongo documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/)

Comment: I tried updateMany and it doesn't work.
Also I don't want to change avasrc2 on email1 match, and avasrc1 on email2 match.

Comment: Can you share collection data like 10 documents data?

Comment: This is a screenshot of chat example from MongoDB.    

https://ibb.co/frB2H5J    

I need change "avasrc1" if (email1: email) or change "avasrc2" if (email2: email)
 and change any "avasrc" in messages array where email: email