# MongoDB update query in subarray

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, object, mongoose

An update in the array of objects inside another array of objects.

mongodb field that I'm working on:

```
otherFields: values,

tasks: [
 {
  _id: mongodb.objectID(),
  title: string,
  items:[{
   _id: mongodb.objectID(),
   title: string,
   completed: boolean        //field need to be update.
  }]
 },
 {}...
],

otherFields: value
```

[sample mongodb document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uyBav.png)

I need to find the document using the *task_id* and the *item_id* and update a completed field in item of a task. Using the mongoose **findOneAndUpdate** method

```
const path = "tasks.$.items." + item_id + "completed";
collectionName.findOneAndUpdate( 
{ _id: req.user._id, "tasks._id": taskID }, 
{ $set: { [path]: true }});
```

The above query doesn't work!!!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: ```
const path = "tasks.$.items." + item_id + "completed";

collectionName.findOneAndUpdate(
      { _id: req.user._id, "tasks._id": taskID },
      { $set: { [path]: true  } }
    );
```
This doesn't work!

Comment: Please edit your question (https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67871554/edit) and add the code there.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use multiple query conditions, since you'd like to update a specific item that has an unique ID. Therefore you could use something along the lines:

```js
collectionName.findOneAndUpdate(
  { 'tasks.items._id': itemID },
  ...
);
```

Keep in mind this structure is far away from optimized as it would basically look through the entire database...

---

Also now that I think of it, you'd also have issue with the update, as there are two nested arrays within the document. Read more here: [How to Update Multiple Array Elements in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669178/how-to-update-multiple-array-elements-in-mongodb/46054172#46054172)