# How do I update all objects in an array in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have the following model and I'm trying to update the 'seen' property to true for all of the objects in the notifications array, but I can't figure out a way to do this using one query?

```
    {
        _id: 'fjkldjasfljsdklfj',
        user_id: 'fjdskjafkldsjadf',
        notifications: [
            {
                seen: false,
                message: 'This is message 1',
                date: '12-03-2021'
            },
            {
                seen: false,
                message: 'This is message 2',
                date: '12-03-2021'
            },
            {
                seen: true,
                message: 'This is message 3',
                date: '12-03-2021'
            },
            {
                seen: false,
                message: 'This is message 4',
                date: '12-03-2021'
            },
        ]
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Update Multiple Array Elements in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669178/how-to-update-multiple-array-elements-in-mongodb)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [all positional operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/) `$[]`:

```
db.collection.updateOne(
   { user_id: 'fjdskjafkldsjadf' },
   { $set: { "notifications.$[].seen": true } }
)
```