# How to update array of an object in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

```
Messages.update(
    {_id: docId, "messages.senderId": friendId},
    {
        $set: {"messages.$[elem].read": true}
    },
    {
        multi: true,
        arrayFilters: [{"elem.senderId": friendId}]
    },
    (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(500).json({message: "Something error occured" + err})
        } else {
            return res.status(200).json({message: "Successfully", result})
        }
    }
)
```

when this command execute I get an error.

**Could not find path "messages.0.senderId" in schema"
and my schema is**

```
const Schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    conversations: Array,
    messages: Array
})
```

How can solve this problem?,
please, help me.

i follow this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669178/how-to-update-multiple-array-elements-in-mongodb/46054172#46054172)  but not work.

Answer (score 2):

This is a `moongoose` error as your schema does not specify the complete structure.
You can see [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8rZCFyKGOSE) that the Mongo update syntax is working as expected.

It seems this is a missing feature for now, As seen in the source code (`mongoose v6`)

```
if (schematype == null) {
  if (!strictQuery) {
    return;
  }
  // For now, treat `strictQuery = true` and `strictQuery = 'throw'` as
  // equivalent for casting array filters. `strictQuery = true` doesn't
  // quite work in this context because we never want to silently strip out
  // array filters, even if the path isn't in the schema.
  throw new Error(`Could not find path "${filterPath}" in schema`);
}
```

The comment acknowledges this bad behaviour, but this is still the logic used even for "mixed type" arrays.

You can either:

1. Update your Array schema to fully describe the object:

```
const Schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    conversations: Array,
    messages: [{senderId: String}]
})
```

2. Pass the `strict: false` option in the update, this will also disable other validations which means it's the less preferable approach:

```
Messages.update(
    {_id: docId, "messages.senderId": friendId},
    {
        $set: {"messages.$[elem].read": true}
    },
    {
        multi: true,
        strict: false,
        arrayFilters: [{"elem.senderId": friendId}]
    },
    (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(500).json({message: "Something error occured" + err})
        } else {
            return res.status(200).json({message: "Successfully", result})
        }
    }
)
```

Comment: but, Brother it is give error during save messages in db after configuration Schema.  My configuration for save messages in db. `const message = await Messages(
                        { conversations: [req.body.adminId, req.body.friend_id],
                            messages: {message: messageChange,time: req.body.time,senderId: req.body.adminId,
                               type: req.body.type,
                                messageID: req.body.messageID,
                                read: req.body.seen

                            }}) message.save()`

Comment: did you add all the relevant fields to the schema? not just senderId

Comment: yes, ` new mongoose.Schema({
    conversations: Array,
    messages: [{
        message: String,
        senderId: String,
        type: String,
        messageID: String,
        read: Boolean,
        time:{ type: String, default: Date.now() }

    }],
})`

Comment: and give this kind of error,,              ValidationError: messages.0: Cast to [string] failed for value \"[\\n' +\n  '  {\\n' +\n  \"    message: 'gek',\\n\" +\n  '    time: 1656852475119,\\n' +\n  \"    senderId: '62bb59979690362946aedb02',\\n\" +\n  \"    type: 'text',\\n\" +\n  '    messageID: 163172,\\n' +\n  '    read: false\\n' +\n  '  }\\n' +\n  ']\" (type string) at path \"messages.0\"","messageId":163172}

Comment: help me brother 

Comment: It seems like it's just a schema type mismatch. ("cast to string failed" ), just make sure if you defined "String" in the schema that the input is also string

Comment: yes, I defined both side but still same error exits.

Comment: it is work. when `conversations: Array,
    messages: [{message: { type: String },time: { type: String },senderId: { type: String },type: { type: String },
        
    }],`  when defined Schema in this type

Answer (score 1):

This is a `moongoose` error as your schema does not specify the complete structure.
You can see [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8rZCFyKGOSE) that the Mongo update syntax is working as expected.

It seems this is a missing feature for now, As seen in the source code (`mongoose v6`)

```
if (schematype == null) {
  if (!strictQuery) {
    return;
  }
  // For now, treat `strictQuery = true` and `strictQuery = 'throw'` as
  // equivalent for casting array filters. `strictQuery = true` doesn't
  // quite work in this context because we never want to silently strip out
  // array filters, even if the path isn't in the schema.
  throw new Error(`Could not find path "${filterPath}" in schema`);
}
```

The comment acknowledges this bad behaviour, but this is still the logic used even for "mixed type" arrays.

You can either:

1. Update your Array schema to fully describe the object:

```
const Schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    conversations: Array,
    messages: [{senderId: String, read: Boolean}]
})
```

2. Pass the `strict: false` option in the update, this will also disable other validations which means it's the less preferable approach:

```
Messages.update(
    {_id: docId, "messages.senderId": friendId},
    {
        $set: {"messages.$[elem].read": true}
    },
    {
        multi: true,
        strict: false,
        arrayFilters: [{"elem.senderId": friendId}]
    },
    (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(500).json({message: "Something error occured" + err})
        } else {
            return res.status(200).json({message: "Successfully", result})
        }
    }
)
```