# How do i update the nested object of array in mongodb following document, explanation below:

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, pymongo

I have this following document. I'm writing an API to update `"dataTracking"` to either `true` or `false`. I'm trying to update based on `"userID"`, `"ulcaApiKey"`, and `"serviceProviderName"`.

```json
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "64462ca4ff7e6dfc24d0eaeab"
  },
  "userID": "6a73afa4fc774dcdb28d5fffsd944511fD",
  "email": "samsaw.somseeyou@gmail.com",
  "firstName": "SAM SAW Master",
  "password": "$2b$12$IMYAkfdXBruXJm75O9P79.cZZHTA0SB9fvJDTN.cg7Fwtu/VBg/JS",
  "isVerified": true,
  "isActive": true,
  "roles": [
    "SAMUEL-DATASETS-CONTRIBUTOR"
  ],
  "apiKeyDetails": [
    {
      "appName": "apspDs",
      "ulcaApiKey": "05ff4569ff-9cc1-4959-a39e-94e90e01de6s",
      "createdTimestamp": "1681467785",
      "serviceProviderKeys": [
        {
          "serviceProviderName": "maddyyyyys",
          "dataTracking": "true",
          "inferenceApiKey": {
            "name": "Authorization",
            "value": "VBM0sd4D82pQsdckvUwBwI62pCP7sYuniYcA4-5cGS4LF77dUSfhxp-yxdvo4qglzJ8"
          }
        },
        {
          "serviceProviderName": "somwthing",
          "dataTracking": "false",
          "inferenceApiKey": {
            "name": "Authorization",
            "value": "qi5tpTvGXsdckMDDiqCfMk_UQIKab8QeRdt3Gse3ZnEnsCtitnMZilU0aPIHCZl6xaC"
          }
        },
        {
          "serviceProviderName": "somehtingfandall",
          "dataTracking": "false",
          "inferenceApiKey": {
            "name": "Authorsization",
            "value": "qi5tpTsdfvGXkMDDiqCfMk_UQIKab8QeRdt3Gse3ZnEnsCtitnMZilU0aPIHCZl6xaC"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "appName": "app",
      "ulcaApiKey": "05ff4569ff-9cc1-4959-a39e-94e90e01de66",
      "createdTimestamp": "1681467785",
      "serviceProviderKeys": [
        {
          "serviceProviderName": "maddyyyyy",
          "dataTracking": "false",
          "inferenceApiKey": {
            "name": "Authorization",
            "value": "VBM0sd4D82pQkvUwBwI62pCP7sYuniYcA4-5cGS4LF77dUSfhxp-yxdvo4qglzJ8"
          }
        },
        {
          "serviceProviderName": "AI4Bharat",
          "dataTracking": "false",
          "inferenceApiKey": {
            "name": "Authorization",
            "value": "qi5tpTvGXkMDDiqCfMk_UQIKab8QeRdt3Gse3ZnEnsCtitnMZilU0aPIHCZl6xaC"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "appName": "appDummy",
      "ulcaApiKey": "05ff4569ff-9cc1-4959-a39e-94e90e01de6D",
      "createdTimestamp": "1681467785",
      "serviceProviderKeys": [
        {
          "serviceProviderName": "dummyMaddy",
          "dataTracking": "true",
          "inferenceApiKey": {
            "name": "Authorization",
            "value": "VBM0sd4D82pQkvUwBwI62pCP7sYuniYcA4-5cGS4LF77dUSfhxp-yxdvo4qglzJ8"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried the following code but I couldn't find the result.

```js
db.getCollection("ulca-user").updateOne(
  {
    "userID": "6a73afa4fc774dcdb28d5fffsd944511fD",
    "apiKeyDetails.ulcaApiKey": "05ff4569ff-9cc1-4959-a39e94e90e01de6s",
    "apiKeyDetails.serviceProviderKeys.serviceProviderName": "maddyyyyys"
  },
  {
    $set:{
      "apiKeyDetails.serviceProviderKeys.dataTracking": "false"
    }
  }
)
```

How do I update `"dataTracking"` using `"userID"`, `"ulcaApiKey"`, and `"serviceProviderName"`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Update Multiple Array Elements in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669178/how-to-update-multiple-array-elements-in-mongodb)

Comment: @ray this does not solve my question as my document is nested differently than the document in comment/link.

Comment: like how? Have you checked out the demonstration of `arrayFilters` in the link? It is the canonical solution to update array elements, regardless of level of array nesting.

Answer (score 0):

Like [@ray commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76220313/how-do-i-update-the-nested-object-of-array-in-mongodb-following-document-explan#comment134412981_76220313), `"arrayFilters"` are very well suited for this use case.  Here's one way you could do it.

```js
db.collection.update({
  "userID": "6a73afa4fc774dcdb28d5fffsd944511fD",
  "apiKeyDetails.ulcaApiKey": "05ff4569ff-9cc1-4959-a39e-94e90e01de6s",
  "apiKeyDetails.serviceProviderKeys.serviceProviderName": "maddyyyyys"
},
{
  "$set": {
    "apiKeyDetails.$[key].serviceProviderKeys.$[name].dataTracking": "false"
  }
},
{
  "arrayFilters": [
    {"key.ulcaApiKey": "05ff4569ff-9cc1-4959-a39e-94e90e01de6s"},
    {"name.serviceProviderName": "maddyyyyys"}
  ]
})
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_uF9dYcsIwx).